# How to add 20 minutes to a current date?

Tags: javascript, datetime

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to add 30 minutes to a javascript Date object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1197928/how-to-add-30-minutes-to-a-javascript-date-object)

I can get the current date object like this:

```
var currentDate = new Date();
```

How can I add 20 minutes to it?

```
var twentyMinutesLater = ?;
```

Comment: @therefromhere: Two thirds of a duplicate, actually ;)

Answer (score 125, accepted):

Use [`.getMinutes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getMinutes) to get the current minutes, then add 20 and use [`.setMinutes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setMinutes) to update the date object.

```
var twentyMinutesLater = new Date();
twentyMinutesLater.setMinutes(twentyMinutesLater.getMinutes() + 20);
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, does it work in any browser, when minutes is >= 40 ? (IE6 I'm looking at you)

Comment: @ring0 - yup, it'll wrap around correctly if adding past the hour, it'll update the hours.

Comment: @VGE: *"probably the most efficient way"* Probably not, the raw value method is probably more efficient. But I can't imagine it *remotely matters* in real-world terms, not even in a tight loop, and the code is nice and clear to anyone doing maintenance on it.

Comment: I would not that this will only be right when you are talking about currentDate being "now". If you want to add twenty minutes to any given date, then the declaration should be
var twentyMinutesLater = new Date(currentDate);

Comment: @JimmyBosse: `new Date(currentDate)` will make a round-trip through a *string* and drop the milliseconds portion of the date. To clone a date accurately (and more efficiently, not that it's likely to matter), you'd want `new Date(+currentDate)`.

Comment: You have to count the minutes in milliseconds.

Answer (score 28):

Add it in milliseconds:

```
var currentDate = new Date();
var twentyMinutesLater = new Date(currentDate.getTime() + (20 * 60 * 1000));
```

Answer (score 11):

Just get the millisecond timestamp and add 20 minutes to it:

```
twentyMinutesLater = new Date(currentDate.getTime() + (20*60*1000))
```

Answer (score 9):

Just add 20 minutes in milliseconds to your date:

```
  var currentDate = new Date();

  currentDate.setTime(currentDate.getTime() + 20*60*1000);
```

Answer (score 7):

```
var d = new Date();
var v = new Date();
v.setMinutes(d.getMinutes()+20);
```

Answer (score 3):

you have a lot of answers in the [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1197928/how-to-add-30-minutes-to-a-javascript-date-object)

```
var d1 = new Date (),
d2 = new Date ( d1 );
d2.setMinutes ( d1.getMinutes() + 20 );
alert ( d2 );
```