# How to create time zone with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I create a local time(`time zone -> UTC + 3:30`) that would show seconds with jQuery?
**I do not want to use a plugin**, and prefer a short code.

I do not use the following example because it gets the system time and is in javascript. It is only an example of what I want.
**EXAMPLE** of javascript: http://jsfiddle.net/HZmPg/

**EDIT:** What is your opinion about this code?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var timezone = "Europe/Berlin";
  $.getJSON("http://json-time.appspot.com/time.json?tz="+timezone+"&callback=?",
    function(data){
      if (data.hour < 12) {
        alert ("Good morning in "+timezone);
      } else {
        alert ("Good afternoon in "+timezone);
      }
    })
});
```

If this can not be done with jQuery, what is the solution?

Comment: jquery really wasn't designed for data manipulation "jQuery is a fast and concise JavaScript Library that simplifies HTML document traversing, event handling, animating, and Ajax interactions". What are you trying to do? When you say local time do you mean server time? The example you have a fiddle of gets the local machine time what more do you want?

Comment: Please edit your post and add the code inside your question.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1197928/how-to-add-30-minutes-to-a-javascript-date-object

Comment: @ plaes - i edit post please see and tell me about it?

Comment: why not keep the time as UTC and then do whatever you want with it? Much easier to keep track of.

Answer (score 0):

You could make this a function with a callback

```
function getTime(timezone, callback) {
        $.getJSON("http://json-time.appspot.com/time.json", {
            tz: timezone,
            callback: '?'
        },
        callback);
    });
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    var timezone = "Europe/Berlin",
        hello = function (time) {
            if (time.hour < 12) {
                alert ("Good morning in "+ timezone);
            } else {
                alert ("Good afternoon in "+ timezone);
            }
        };
    getTime(timezone, hello);
}
```

Or you could use deferred objects an promises to clean things up:

```
function getTime(timezone) {
    return $.getJSON("http://json-time.appspot.com/time.json?tz="+timezone+"&callback=?").promise();
}


$(document).ready(function(){
    var timezone = "Europe/Berlin",
        hello = function (time) {
            if (time.hour < 12) {
                alert ("Good morning in "+ timezone);
            } else {
                alert ("Good afternoon in "+ timezone);
            }
        };
    getTime(timezone).done(hello);
});
```