# Add 10 seconds to a Date

Tags: javascript

How can I add 10 seconds to a JavaScript date object?

Something like this:

```
var timeObject = new Date()     
var seconds = timeObject.getSeconds() + 10;
timeObject = timeObject + seconds;
```

Comment: Or if you want to do it via the constructor -  new Date(new Date().getTime() + 10000)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add 30 minutes to a JavaScript Date object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1197928/how-to-add-30-minutes-to-a-javascript-date-object)

Comment: you can also simply `new Date(+timeObject + seconds * 1000)`

Answer (score 616, accepted):

There's a [`setSeconds`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setSeconds) method as well:

```
var t = new Date();
t.setSeconds(t.getSeconds() + 10);
```

For a list of the *other* `Date` functions, [you should check out MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

---

`setSeconds` will correctly handle wrap-around cases:

```js
var d;
d = new Date('2014-01-01 10:11:55');
alert(d.getMinutes() + ':' + d.getSeconds()); //11:55
d.setSeconds(d.getSeconds() + 10);
alert(d.getMinutes() + ':0' + d.getSeconds()); //12:05
```

Comment: Beware, my Nodejs installation returns d.getSeconds() as a string. I had to change this to

(+d.getSeconds())

The unary plus converts a string to a number. Perhaps a little more obvious would be

1*d.getSeconds()

Comment: @tqwhite, `typeof new Date().getSeconds()` returns `'number'` in node, so I think you may have other issues (unless you're on an outdated version of node or something).

Comment: Try doing `d.setSeconds(d.getSeconds() - 92);` and you'll end up with 2'32" difference instead of 1'32". The solution with `new Date(d.getTime() - 92*1000);` works however !

Comment: @Rafalon, [that doesn't appear to be the case](https://jsfiddle.net/6cwq8rm1/), please double check and provide a working example of the behavior you describe.

Comment: @zzzzBov which browser do you use ? I was on IE11 when I noticed the difference, I'll doublecheck tomorrow

Comment: Relying on undocumented behavior (that setSeconds(70) will increment minutes by one and set seconds to 10) seems like a generally bad practice. The (currently next) answers pointing to Date.getTime() + <number of milliseconds to add> seem to be the intended and supported approach, and would be clear to most programmers coming from different languages without encyclopedic knowledge of the undocumented nuances of each particular JavaScript engine.

Comment: @TomDibble, wrt undocumented behavior: [ECMAScript specifies the behavior of `Date.prototype.setSeconds`](http://es5.github.io/#x15.9.5.30). Of course, I have linked to the ES5 spec, which has been superseded by later ECMAScript specifications, but the point still stands that the behavior should be considered documented, and any variations are likely implementation bugs.

Comment: @Rafalon, I noticed some issues with my prior example for IE11, it didn't like the format I used in the `Date` declaration (and the use of `const`), so here's an [updated example](https://jsfiddle.net/rtd8vc6a/).

Comment: An issue could occur with historical time zones, see comments underneath @Ron's answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17267937/198797. Possibly not a common scenario but an issue nonetheless.

Answer (score 188):

```
let timeObject = new Date();
const milliseconds = 10 * 1000; // 10 seconds = 10000 milliseconds
timeObject = new Date(timeObject.getTime() + milliseconds);
```

Comment: ... and the reason you added 10000 is because Javascript dates work in milliseconds, i.e. 10000 = 10 * 1000

Comment: And the + before timeObject is needed because it casts timeObject to a number. So its like timeObject.getTime() in Ron's answer

Comment: Quick kinda-obvious tip: if you're adding seconds to the current date, you can shorten the code a little bit by using `Date.now()`. Example: `const timeObject = new Date(Date.now() + milliseconds);`

Comment: Why are the first two lines commented? These should be uncommented for the code to work properly ☝

Answer (score 108):

Just for the performance maniacs among us.

### getTime

```
var d = new Date('2014-01-01 10:11:55');
d = new Date(d.getTime() + 10000);
```

**5,196,949 Ops/sec,  fastest**

---

### setSeconds

```
var d = new Date('2014-01-01 10:11:55');
d.setSeconds(d.getSeconds() + 10);
```

**2,936,604 Ops/sec, 43% slower**

---

### moment.js

```
var d = new moment('2014-01-01 10:11:55');
d = d.add(10, 'seconds');
```

**22,549 Ops/sec, 100% slower**

---

So maybe its the least human readable (not that bad) but the fastest way of going :)

[jspref online tests](http://jsperf.com/add-seconds-to-date)

Comment: Thanks for the details, very useful :)

Comment: Super useful, thanks for the detailed answer !

Answer (score 65):

```
const timeObject = new Date(); 
timeObject = new Date(timeObject.getTime() + 1000 * 10);
console.log(timeObject);
```

**Also please refer:**
[How to add 30 minutes to a JavaScript Date object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1197928/how-to-add-30-minutes-to-a-javascript-date-object)

Comment: of all the wrong answers here, this is the correct one.

Comment: Yes, this is the correct answer. Unfortunately Google is referring to this Question if searching for "javascript date add seconds" and the most voted answer is wrong.

Comment: Can anybody please explain what the selected answer (currently from @zzzzBov) is doing wrong? It works for me.

Comment: @tsemer I think that works. From MDN: If a parameter you specify is outside of the expected range, setSeconds() attempts to update the date information in the Date object accordingly. For example, if you use 100 for secondsValue, the minutes stored in the Date object will be incremented by 1, and 40 will be used for seconds.

Comment: Thanks Ron, but I'm not challenging if your answer works. I'm wondering why @CoryMawhorter wrote that the other answers are all wrong, and 4 others upvoted his comment. For me they both work, in which case it's a matter of taste.

Comment: @tsemer, at the first glance, I thought zzzzBov's answer is not right, because I didn't think it will update the minute value if it is out of the range. But because of your "challenging", I reviewed the MDN, and confirmed that answer is definitely right. :)

Comment: @tsemer I'm not sure exactly, but IIRC it had something to do with differences in setSeconds implementations creating hidden problems.  That may have changed, but `.getTime() + (1000 * seconds)` is a guaranteed-to-work way AFAIK.

Comment: Thanks @CoryMawhorter. If you ever come across those hidden problems I'm sure the community would appreciate it if you post them here :)

Comment: @tsemer Try in a web browser with Historical TimeZones support (Internet Explorer 11,for example): Also set your system TimeZone to "Asia/Yekaterinburg": `var timestamp = Date.parse("2011-03-26T20:59:59.999Z");
var d = new Date(timestamp);
d.setSeconds(d.getSeconds() + 10);
console.log(d.getTime() - timestamp);`

Comment: @tsemer i've been using the simpler techniques for ages now.  it must've been vendor specific and short lived.  ignore my previous comment ;]

Comment: @CoryMawhorter, good to know thank you :) however:
@4esn0k, nice catch! This is indeed an example where this answer works and @zzzzBov's misses by 1 hour. Side by side test: `var timestamp = Date.parse("2011-03-26T20:59:59.999Z"); var d1 = new Date(timestamp); d1.setSeconds(d1.getSeconds() + 10); var d2 = new Date(timestamp + 10000); console.log(d1); console.log(d2);` using IE 11 and with system time set to Yekaterinburg. I'm not sure how likely it is, but it exists.

Answer (score 11):

Try this

```
a = new Date();
a.setSeconds(a.getSeconds() + 10);
```

Answer (score 5):

I have a couple of new variants

1. `var t = new Date(Date.now() + 10000);`
2. `var t = new Date(+new Date() + 10000);`

Answer (score 4):

```
timeObject.setSeconds(timeObject.getSeconds() + 10)
```

Answer (score 2):

The `Date()` object in javascript is not that smart really.

If you just focus on adding seconds it seems to handle things smoothly but if you try to add X number of seconds then add X number of minute and hours, etc, to the same `Date` object you end up in trouble. So I simply fell back to only using the `setSeconds()` method and converting my data into seconds (which worked fine).

If anyone can demonstrate adding time to a global `Date()` object using all the set methods and have the final time come out correctly I would like to see it but I get the sense that one set method is to be used at a time on a given `Date()` object and mixing them leads to a mess.

```
var vTime = new Date();

var iSecondsToAdd = ( iSeconds + (iMinutes * 60) + (iHours * 3600) + (iDays * 86400) );

vTime.setSeconds(iSecondsToAdd);
```

[Here is some more documentation that may help](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp):

Answer (score 2):

1. you can use `setSeconds` method by getting seconds from today and just adding 10 seconds in it

   ```
   var today = new Date();
   today.setSeconds(today.getSeconds() + 10);
   ```
2. You can add 10 *1000 milliseconds to the new date:

   ```
   var today = new Date(); 
   today = new Date(today.getTime() + 1000*10);
   ```
3. You can use `setTime`:

   ```
   today.setTime(now.getTime() + 10000)
   ```

Answer (score 2):

The `.setSeconds` revealed quite strange misbehavior for me under node.js, so I use:

```
dateAddSeconds(date, seconds){ 
    return new Date( Date.parse(date) + seconds*1000 );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this way.

```
Date.prototype.addSeconds = function(seconds) {
  var copiedDate = new Date(this.getTime());
  return new Date(copiedDate.getTime() + seconds * 1000);
}
```

Just call and assign `new Date().addSeconds(10)`

Answer (score 1):

If you need to add 10 seconds to current time you can use:

```
const date = new Date();
date.setUTCSeconds(date.getUTCSeconds() + 10); // Change 10 to any number of seconds
```

Comment: If you do that, you are setting the value to 10, not adding 10.

Comment: @Dicren Thanks for the warning, I've modified the answer...

Answer (score 0):

Few years ago i've wrote a 'generic' date function:

```
function addToDate({time_unit, operator, offset_value }) {
        const date = new Date();
  operator = operator == "after" ? "+" : "-";
  switch (time_unit) {
    case "seconds":
        date.setSeconds(eval(`${date.getSeconds()} ${operator} ${offset_value}`));
    break;

    case "hours":
        date.setHours(eval(`${date.getHours()} ${operator} ${offset_value}`));
      break;

    case "minutes":
        date.setMinutes(eval(`${date.getMinutes()} ${operator} ${offset_value}`));

      break;
    case "days":
        date.setDate(eval(`${date.getDate()} ${operator} ${offset_value}`));
      break;

    case "months":
        date.setMonth(eval(`${date.getMonth()} ${operator} ${offset_value}`));

      break;
    case "years":
        date.setFullYear(eval(`${date.getFullYear()} ${operator} ${offset_value}`));
      break;
    default:
      break;
  }

  return date;
}

const new_date = addToDate({time_unit:'seconds','operator':'after','offset_value':10});

console.log(new_date.toISOString());
```