# Adding a second to datetime using javascript

Tags: javascript, datetime

How to add a second to a date in below format in Javascript?

```
x = '2015-05-23 11:20:33';

setInterval(function () {
  console.log(x+1);  //Looking something in this place to add a second and show in the same format
}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [setSeconds()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setSeconds)

```js
var date = new Date('2015-05-23 11:20:33');

setInterval(function () {
  date.setSeconds(date.getSeconds() + 1);
  console.log(
    date.getFullYear()+'-'+
    (date.getMonth()+1)+'-'+
    date.getDate()+' '+
    date.getHours()+':'+
    date.getMinutes()+':'+
    date.getSeconds()
    );//to ensure log is  'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS' format
}, 1000);
```

See [Add 10 seconds to a Javascript date object timeObject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7687884/add-10-seconds-to-a-javascript-date-object-timeobject)

Comment: This shows the output in milliseconds.  I want the time in the same format as 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS' and in the above example it should start exactly from '2015-05-23 11:20:34'.