# adding and substracting time in Javascript

Tags: javascript, date, time

I'm trying to add five minutes to the current time using milliseconds and am baffled why adding and subtracting give such different results:

```js
const now = new Date();
const gimmeFive = now + 300000;
const takeFive = now - 300000;
```

Respectively give:

```
"Sun May 31 2020 23:06:48 GMT+0100 (British Summer Time)300000"

1590962508207
```

Why does subtraction work, but not addition? How can I add time?

---

<sub>**Added clarification per stack overflow prompt:** while the Q here overlapped with [Add 10 seconds to a Date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7687884/add-10-seconds-to-a-date), it differed in seeking to understand why the add and subtract operators show different behaviours (as explained by RobG, for which, much thanks!)</sub>

Comment: coerce it to a number first or use .getTime() or Date.now.  `+` with a Date will try to coerce to a string first.  `-` is not an operator for strings, so it will try to coerce to number.  It's part of the conversion rules.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add 10 seconds to a Date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7687884/add-10-seconds-to-a-date)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add 30 minutes to a JavaScript Date object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1197928/how-to-add-30-minutes-to-a-javascript-date-object)

Comment: @Mina as to "why", it's because that's how the specs of the language are designed.  You can follow the conversion path: https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-addition-operator-plus   basically ToPrimitive -> ToString is attempted first.   And for subtraction: https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-subtraction-operator-minus

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why does subtraction work, but not addition? How can I add time?

As user120242 says in the first comment, the [addition operator (+)](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-addition-operator-plus) is overloaded and does either arithmetic addition or string addition (concatenation) depending on the types of values used (see [Runtime Semantics: ApplyStringOrNumericBinaryOperator](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-applystringornumericbinaryoperator)).

So in the case of:

```
new Date() + 300000;
```

the Date is first [converted to a primitive](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-toprimitive), which returns a string. If either the left or right operands are stings, they're both converted to string and then the two strings are concatenated.

In the case of:

```
new Date() - 300000;
```

the [subtraction operator (-)](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-subtraction-operator-minus) coerces values to number, so the Date is converted to its time value and the right hand value is subtracted.

If you want to add 300 seconds to a Date, you can use one of the following:

```js
let d = new Date();
let ms = 300000;

// Add 3 seconds to the time value, creates a new Date
let e = new Date(d.getTime() + ms)
console.log(e.toString());

// As above but use unary operator + to coerce Date to number
let f = new Date(+d + ms)
console.log(f.toString());

// Use get/setMilliseconds, modifies the Date
d.setMilliseconds(d.getMilliseconds() + ms)
console.log(d.toString());

// Use Date.now
let g = new Date(Date.now() + ms);
console.log(g.toString());
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this `Date.now()+300000` and `Date.now()-300000`

P.S. put everything on your constants of course

```
typeof (new Date)   // returns "object"
typeof (Date.now()) // returns "number"

/* --------------------------------- //
SO, of course, you cannot add or subtract numbers from, 
and to objects. Follow the rules, make calculations with 
numbers and everything will be OK. 
*/


// your code might look like this
const now = Date.now();
const gimmeFive = now + 300000;
const takeFive = now - 300000;
```

`Date.now()` method returns the number of milliseconds elapsed since January 1, 1970 00:00:00 UTC. Instead you can use `new Date().getTime()` – it will also return you a number in milliseconds.

Answer (score 1):

`new Date()` returns an object. You should not be adding or subtracting time directly on the object.

Instead, you can use `Date.now()` which returns the current time in milliseconds elapsed since Jan 1 1970.

```
const now = Date.now();
const gimmeFive = now + 300000;
const takeFive = now - 300000;

console.log(new Date(gimmeFive)); // Sun May 31 2020 18:42:20 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)
console.log(new Date(takeFive)); // Sun May 31 2020 18:32:20 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)
```

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

That being said, if it is possible in your project, I suggest working with [momentjs](https://momentjs.com/). It is truly a life saver when it comes to manipulating dates.

I hope this helps. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with minutes best solution is to use Date's `getMinutes` and `setMinutes` methods.

```js
var dt = new Date();
console.log(dt)

dt.setMinutes( dt.getMinutes() + 100 );
console.log(dt)

dt.setMinutes( dt.getMinutes() - 100 );
console.log(dt)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
new Date(now.getTime() + 5 * 60000)
```

as new Date always return Object,

```
new Date() - 1 // Return (new Date).getMilliseconds() similar to "1"-1 = 0
new Date() + 1 // Return string similar to "1"+1 = "11"
```