# How to add time to a firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database

I need to add time to a admin.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP and later retrieve it. But when I try to [add additional time](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7688011/4833705) to the`ServerValue.TIMESTAMP` I get an error:

> getTime is not a function

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();

const ten_secs = 10 * 1000; // 10 seconds
const daily_secs = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000; // 24 hrs
const weekly_secs = 168 * 60 * 60 * 1000; // 1 week

exports.update = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {

    const currentTimeStamp = admin.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP;

    const updatedSecs = new Date(currentTimeStamp.getTime() + ten_secs); // should be saved in the db as milliseconds for later retrieve and calculations

    const updatedDay = new Date(currentTimeStamp.getTime() + daily_secs); // should be saved in the db as milliseconds for later retrieve and calculations

    const updatedWeek = new Date(currentTimeStamp.getTime() + weekly_secs); // should be saved in the db as milliseconds for later retrieve and calculations

    console.log("updatedSecs: " + updatedSecs + " | updatedDay: " + updatedDay + " | updatedWeek: " + updatedWeek);

    const ref = admin.database().ref('schedule').child("scheduleId_123").child("my_uid")

    ref.once('value', snapshot => {

        if (!snapshot.exists()) {

            return ref.set({ "updatedSecs": updatedSecs, "updatedDay": updatedDay, "updatedWeek": updatedWeek });

        } else {

            const retrieved_updatedSecs = snapshot.child("updatedSecs").val();
            const retrieved_updatedDay = snapshot.child("updatedDay").val();
            const retrieved_updatedWeek = snapshot.child("updatedWeek").val();

            const currentTime = Date.now();

            // do some calculations with the above values and currentTime.
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ServerValue.TIMESTAMP` is not a standard integer timstamp value that you can do math on.  It's a token, or sentinel value, that gets interpreted on the server when it receives the write.  That's how it's able to take the actual server's timestamp value.  The only way it makes sense to use is as a child's value at the time of a write.

Since you are running in Cloud Functions, you actually have a Google server timestamp value right there in memory - in the actual clock.  All of Googles backends have synchronized clocks, so they are all accurate.  You typically only use `ServerValue.TIMESTAMP` in a client app when you can't be certain that the user's device has an accurate clock.

In your case, instead of using `ServerValue.TIMESTAMP`, you should simply take [`Date.now()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/now) as the current time.

Answer (score 0):

You need a closing parentheses after currentTimeStamp.

```
const updatedSecs = new Date(currentTimeStamp).getTime() + ten_secs;
```

Comment: If that works, you did the same thing each time you added time. I also removed the closing parentheses after ten_secs

Comment: I added the same exact code that you did, I get the same error: `getTime is not a function`

Comment: You did same thing on the other lines you used getTime(). Fix each instance

Comment: that code results in a `NaN` value: `@firebase/database: FIREBASE WARNING: Exception was thrown by user callback. Error: Reference.set failed: First argument contains NaN in property`

Comment: read @DougStevenson answer. thanks for trying to help me!

Answer (score 0):

[@DougStevenson's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64762661/4833705) answer worked but I ran into another problem where `getTime is not a function` still kept appearing. I had to use `.valueOf()` instead.

Here is the updated code:

```
const currentTimeStamp = Date.now(); // DougStevenson answer

const updatedSecs = currentTimeStamp.valueOf() + ten_secs;

const updatedDay = currentTimeStamp.valueOf() + daily_secs;

const updatedWeek = currentTimeStamp.valueOf() + weekly_secs;
```