# How to add time to a date in js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I get a date with string type from API and then I parse it to a date type so that I can use it for a count down.
I want to add 30 days to the date that I've got from API.

Here is the code that I parsed

```
  const time = Date.parse("2020-12-30T18:35:43");
```

I've already read this question and I tried to implement it

[Add 10 seconds to a Date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7687884/add-10-seconds-to-a-date)

but react does not recognize the getDate

if you need more information, please let me know

Comment: If you are having frequent manipulations with date and time, a much easier solution would be to use [moment](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/add/)

Comment: Please show your attempt at implementing the duplicate, including any errors you received.

Comment: There is no difference between a `Date` object in React and a `Date` object without React. `time`, however, is not a `Date` object. See [MDN's documentation of `Date.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse), where it notes that it "returns the number of milliseconds". Note also that `new Date(string)` calls `Date.parse(string)` implicitly, so just use `new Date(string)`.

Answer (score 2):

You need to wrap your parsed date with a `new Date()`

```js
const time = new Date(Date.parse("2020-12-30T18:35:43"));
// As mention by other comments, this is enough
// const time = new Date("2020-12-30T18:35:43");

time.setSeconds(time.getSeconds() + 10) // 1609349753000
```

`setSeconds` and `getSeconds` are method of the Date, you was trying to execute them on a number.

EDIT :

Answer can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/563406/add-days-to-javascript-datejavascript-date)
In a general way you should use date-fns for date manipulations ;)

Comment: it shows me an error `getSeconds is not a function` how can i fix it ?

Comment: Can you give me more info about your execution context.
Cause I launched it into the browser console and it's working.

Comment: `new Date(string)` uses `Date.parse(string)` behind the scenes. So this would be exactly the same result.. Also the OP wants to add 30 days, not 10 seconds.

Comment: @louisSchneider Sorry my example was based on the link you provided 
Here is a solution to your problem
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/563406/add-days-to-javascript-date

Day manipulation are tricky. I recommend you to use date-fns

Answer (score 1):

you can also setDate to your existing date. Check following code.

```
const date = new Date("2020-12-30T18:35:43");
date.setDate(date.getDate() + 30);
```