# adding 30 minutes to time using javascript - not working

Tags: javascript

need some help with adding extra time to current time

```
currentTime= new Date(); 
var hours2 = currentTime.getHours() + 4;
var minutes2 = currentTime.setMinutes(currentTime.getMinutes() + 30);
```

however it outputs as: 15:1455880112692PM and does not seem to be adding 4.5 hours? anyone have any ideas on this?

Comment: Post outdated please see here > http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1197928/how-to-add-30-minutes-to-a-javascript-date-object

Comment: Ive already looked at those examples, which are the same as mine but output is different

Comment: and you should be expecting your result stored in `currentTime`. Is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you are not getting the minutes, you are getting the Date object. The `setMinutes` method doesn't return the minutes, it returns the Date object itself. Converting a Date object to a string to display it gives you the time in milliseconds since epoch.

First convert the time, so that you get a correct time that wraps over, and not something like `27:93` instead of `04:33`.

```
currentTime = new Date();
currentTime.setHours(currentTime.getHours() + 4);
currentTime.setMinutes(currentTime.getMinutes() + 30);
```

Then you can get the hours and minutes from it:

```
var hours2 = currentTime.getHours();
var minutes2 = currentTime.getMinutes();
```

Instead of adding 4 hours and 30 minutes, you can add 270 minutes:

```
currentTime = new Date();
currentTime.setMinutes(currentTime.getMinutes() + 270);
```

Answer (score 1):

I have a few ideas as to what's wrong:

```
currentTime= new Date(); 
var hours2 = currentTime.getHours() + 4;//doesn't call the setHours method
var minutes2 = currentTime.setMinutes(currentTime.getMinutes() + 30);//works fine for me
```

So

```
currentTime= new Date(); 
var hours2 = currentTime.setHours(currentTime.getHours() + 4);//doesn't call the setHours method
var minutes2 = currentTime.setMinutes(currentTime.getMinutes() + 30);//works fine for me
```

Does work fine, however, you could just do this in a one-liner:

```
currentTime.setMinutes(currentTime.getMinutes() + 270);
//or in seconds:
currentTime.setSeconds(currentTime.getSeconds() + 270*60);//16200 === 4.5 hrs
//or miliseconds:
currentTime.setTime(currentTime.getTime() + 270*60000);//16200000 === 4.5 hrs
```

Answer (score 0):

You never set the hours. Try:

```
currentTime= new Date(); 
currentTime.setHours(currentTime.getHours() + 4);
currentTime.setMinutes(currentTime.getMinutes() + 30);
```

Comment: i now get: 1347891390682:1347893190682PM

Answer (score 0):

Try this I really dont see what the problem you are having is?
http://jsfiddle.net/H9edz/

```
currentTime= new Date(); 
var hours2 = currentTime.getHours() + 4;
var minutes2 = currentTime.setMinutes(currentTime.getMinutes() + 30);
document.write("Ending Time: " + currentTime);
document.write("<br/>");
document.write("Ending Minute: " + currentTime.getMinutes());
document.write("<br/>");
var now = new Date();
now.setMinutes(now.getMinutes() + 30);
document.write("Example Time - From Post:" + now)
```

​