# Manipulate time variable in javascript - add hours to time variable

Tags: javascript, titanium

I am getting data by using a json file and one of the variable is about time, like 19:00, as GMT+0. If i would like to convert this to GMT+2, i will need to add 2, but i couldnt figure out how... I am trying to do this in a Titanium project.

Comment: Isn't json returning an ascii text value?   If so, can't you just replace the +0 with a +2?

Comment: no, the variable is just "19:00", how can i edit it so that it become "21:00" as gmt+2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var time = "19:00";
function incHour(t,hr){ return parseInt(hr) + 2; }
time = time.replace( /^(\d{1,2})/, incHour );
```

Answer (score 1):

i always recommend momentjs, if you think you are going to have to do more time manipulation

http://momentjs.com/

Answer (score 0):

Ref: [How to add 30 minutes to a JavaScript Date object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1197928/how-to-add-30-minutes-to-a-javascript-date-object)

```
var d1 = new Date ('6/29/2011 4:52:48 PM'),
    d2 = new Date ( d1 );
d2.setHours ( d1.getHours() + 2 );
alert ( d2 );
```