# jQuery - Calculate date, six months from the input value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've an input textbox that you write a date, and I would like a way to calculate six months from the input date.
The input date format is:

```
dd/mm/yy
```

Example how it should work:
Input date: `01/07/13`
How the output from the function should be: `01/01/14`

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1197928/how-to-add-30-minutes-to-a-javascript-date-object

Comment: Use `.split()` to separate the components. Add six to the month. If it's greater than twelve, subtract twelve and increment the year by one. You know, *exactly the same way you'd do it on paper.*

Comment: Thank you very much @G_M I could use that. Should I delete this question?

Comment: this will help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16217214/jquery-calculate-date-six-months-from-the-input-value

Comment: @Blazemonger Except when you're on the 29th and 6 months from now is February, unless of course it will be a leap year.  I have seen so many bugs in "Professional" date manipulation, I'd assume leave it up to a library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a `Date`:

```
var date = new Date(year, month, day);
```

To get 6 months later, use:

```
date.setMonth(date.getMonth() + 6);
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/GF6B6/

Comment: +1 for not re-inventing the wheel.  Also, there are plenty of libraries in JS that handle date if you don't want to use the built in Date prototype.