# How can I run a loop with a 15 min interval using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can I run a Javascript loop with a 15 min time interval?  It should use 24 hour format.  For example, running from 6:00 am to 11:45 pm it would run at 6:00,6:15, 6:30 --- 23:45  etc.  These values are displayed as pulldown menu items in html.  I am using notepad for javascript and html because I am required to.

Comment: I'm confused. Are you trying to create a list of times with 15 minute intervals, or to run some thing every 15 minutes from some arbitrary start time, or from a particular start time, or to run something at specific times that just happen to be at 15 minutes intervals?

Comment: Don't downvote for a new bee...

Comment: no dont want to run somthing in evry 15 min

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1197928/how-to-add-30-minutes-to-a-javascript-date-object This might be helpful for you I think.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
setInterval(function() {
 //  I will run for every 15 minutes
}, 15 * 60 * 1000);
```

Comment: How will that ensure that the loop will run at 0600, 0615, etc.?

Comment: that is example he said.He need 15 minutes interval

Comment: Thanq but we dont use any functions just use for loop to iterate the intervals

Comment: no dont want to run somthing in evry 15  min my requirment is  two text boxes start time  and end time when we click on start time text box is shows the list items as 6:00 ,6:15,6:30 ----23:45  thats it and selected values displayes in text box need to write basic same as end time also

Comment: use getTime() in the function to check if you are in your desired period and run script or not. It's not possible give js fixed timestamps like you want. But if you can assume to start the script at specific time, you may consider nesting setInterval(). One for  every 15 minutes and one wrapping e.g. with 6h....