# Add 15 minutes to string in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

`var time="18:15:00"`

I am getting time in 24 hour format like above string.
i have to add 15 minutes to time how can i add.
Without using `substring()`.

`var time`  is string not a `date object`.
Search on google but not get it.

Comment: *Without using substring function* why this limitation?

Comment: Convert it to a Date, add 15 minutes, convert back to string?

Comment: How do you get this string in the first place?

Comment: @alex: Because using string operations to modify dates/times is horrible in the first place.

Comment: @ThiefMaster It is to *modify*, but it's a useful tool for extracting parts of a date (though `split()` would be my suggestion in this example).

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1197928/how-to-add-30-minutes-to-a-javascript-date-object

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can do like this:

```
 function addMinutes(time, minsToAdd) {
  function D(J){ return (J<10? '0':'') + J;};
  var piece = time.split(':');
  var mins = piece[0]*60 + +piece[1] + +minsToAdd;

  return D(mins%(24*60)/60 | 0) + ':' + D(mins%60);  
}  

addMinutes('18:15:00', '20');  // '18:35'
```

[**DEMO Plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/7k9BZwaEMTf6RixHnDGr?p=preview)

Comment: Yeah for that simply do like this `var mins = piece[0]*60 + +piece[1] + -minsToAdd;` you can play with plunker

Comment: @DhavalMarthak or pass -20 instead of 20.

Comment: Thanks. I was having a hard time trying to get a solution for this

Answer (score 3):

Dhavals answer is very nice, but I prefer simple & single-line code.
Therefore, I'd use following:

```
var minsToAdd = 15;
var time = "15:57";
var newTime = new Date(new Date("1970/01/01 " + time).getTime() + minsToAdd * 60000).toLocaleTimeString('en-UK', { hour: '2-digit', minute: '2-digit', hour12: false });
```

*(If you need the seconds, just add `second: '2-digit'` to the formatting options.*)

Further Information: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleTimeString

Answer (score 0):

Just convert the `Original time string` to `time` 
then convert added time string to time then add them

```js
  var time="18:15:00"; // Original Time
  var timeToadd = "00:15:00";  // Time to be added in min
  var timeToAddArr = timeToadd.split(":");             
  var ms = (60 * 60 * parseInt(timeToAddArr[0]) + 60 * (parseInt(timeToAddArr[1])) ) * 1000;
  
  var newTime =new Date('1970-01-01T' + time ).getTime() + ms
  var finalTime = new Date(newTime).toLocaleString('en-GB').slice(12 ,20)

  console.log(finalTime)
```