# Add value to date based on radio button selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I seem to be locating answers here and other locations that are close to what I need -- so my apologies if I've duplicated without noticing. And I'm certain that what I've been locating can work...if I knew how to use it :)

I have 4 radio buttons on a page. They have values as 4, 7, 14, 30.

```
<input type="radio" id="radio1" name="length" value="4"/><label for="radio1">4 DAYS</label>
<input type="radio" id="radio2" name="length" value="7"/><label for="radio2">7 DAYS</label>
<input type="radio" id="radio3" name="length" value="14"/><label for="radio3">14 DAYS</label>
<input type="radio" id="radio4" name="length" value="30"/><label for="radio4">30 DAYS</label>
```

A return date is needed based on the above selection. Say if radio2 is selected, the return date will be the date selected + 7 days.

Here http://jsfiddle.net/JKGvD/525/ is a great example of this functionality however you can see I'm attempting to manipulate the 'nights' field with user input from above.

I attempted to use the `$('input:radio[name=length]:checked').val();` in that Fiddle however it fails with Nan (Not a Number?) in the field.

Please alert me if any further information is needed. And thank you in advance everyone!

Comment: Your jsFiddle doesn't include the radio buttons or the jQuery you mentioned trying...

Comment: `jQuery performs best when scoped correctly, and selecting by ID is always the highest performing selector. `

Comment: @Zenith My apologies, goofed with the link. Updated [here](http://jsfiddle.net/JKGvD/525/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function addMinutes(date, minutes) {
    return new Date(date.getTime() + minutes*60000);
}
```

per

[How to add 30 minutes to a JavaScript Date object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1197928/how-to-add-30-minutes-to-a-javascript-date-object)

Converting your days to minutes we have 1 day = 24 hours = 1440 minutes.

So if you want it in days change the constant accordingly by multiplying by 1440.

To get the radio button value use

```
$('input[name=radioName]:checked', '#myForm').val()
```

per

[How can I know which radio button is selected via jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/596351/how-can-i-get-which-radio-is-selected-via-jquery)

Comment: Thank you for this and your information about selecting id over name. I wasn't aware of this yet.

Comment: I do agree but [http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) I can't it seems

Comment: Damn newbie status. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

Try casting it to a number, like:

```
+$('input:radio[name=length]:checked').val();
```

Remember that HTML values are Strings.

Comment: Ah yes, this was the issue. I was not adding this line in the correct area! I've update the Fiddle [link](http://jsfiddle.net/JKGvD/525/) (this time it's the right link, my apologies above). The value added is slightly off but I'll look into this. Thanks all!