# Convert string to date and get difference

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, nosql, schema

I have few data records like this in 'food' schema -mongodb

```
{
    "_id": "5b220199acbec1409cbf84dd",
    "Name": "Mongo",
    "ID_No": "BA1233",
    "Content": "Bottle",
    "No_packages": 5,
    "No_items": 6,
    "Qty": 30,
    "Mfg": "2018-05-27",
    "Exp": "2018-06-30",
    "__v": 0
  }
```

I want to get the data set where the date difference(Exp-today Date) is less than  30.
I tried it using the following command. But it didn't work.

```
db.food.find({$lt: { $subtract: [ Date() , Exp ],"30"}}  )
```

Comment: is there anyway that i can get the difference from a string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use first  [`$dateFromString` `(aggregation)`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateFromString/)
convert date from string to date format and then [$redact (aggregation)](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/#pipe._S_redact)
 to eliminates the unmatched documents

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$addFields": {
    "date": {
      "$dateFromString": {
        "dateString": "$EXP"
      }
    }
  }},
  { "$redact": {
    "$cond": [
      { "$lt": [
        { "$divide": [
          { "$subtract": [new Date(), "$date"] },
          1000 * 60 * 60 * 24
        ]},
        30
      ]},
      "$$KEEP",
      "$$PRUNE"
    ]
  }}
])
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken, you want documents with Exp - today's date less than 30 days. In other words, today's date + 30 days >= Exp. Converting 30 days to milliseconds

Try the following:

```
db.food.aggregate(
    {
        $project: {
            _id: 0,
            Name: 1,
            exp_date_calc: new Date(ISODate().getTime() + 30 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000).toISOString()
        },
    }, {
        $match: { exp_date_calc: { $gt: "$Exp" } }
    }
);
```

or may be this one:

```
db.food.aggregate(
    {
        $project: {
            _id: 0,
            Name: 1,
            expdate: {
                $dateFromString: {
                    dateString: '$Exp'
                }
            },
            exp_date_calc: new Date(ISODate().getTime() + 30 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)
        },
    }, {
        $match: { exp_date_calc: { $gte: "$expdate" } }
    }
);
```

Refer: [Adding/Subtracting days to ISODate in MongoDB Shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30996728/adding-subtracting-days-to-isodate-in-mongodb-shell)