# Need to compare 2 different date fields in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have two date fields in my `Mongo` Database and I would like to compare their difference (i.e. their "Age")  with a value a value in years.

**For example:** I would like to find the `Pharmacies` that are older than 15 years.

(CurrentDate - EstablishedDate) > 15 (keep in mind the `CurrentYear` as it might not be of today's date) 
 What is the way to do this?

**Sample array of documents below:**

```
[
  {
    "Pharmacy": "a",
    "EstablishedDate": ISODate("2006-10-12"),
    "CurrentDate": ISODate("2018-07-17"),
    "Medicine": [
      {
        "MedName": "MedA",
        "Quantity": 55,
        "Type": "Admission"
      },
      {
        "MedName": "MedB",
        "Quantity": 34,
        "Type": "Admission"
      },
      {
        "MedName": "MedD",
        "Quantity": 25,
        "Type": "Discharge",

      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "Pharmacy": "b",
    "EstablishedDate": ISODate("2015-02-02"),
    "CurrentDate": ISODate("2018-07-17"),
    "Medicine": [
      {
        "MedName": "MedB",
        "Quantity": 60,
        "Type": "Critical"
      },
      {
        "MedName": "MedC",
        "Quantity": 34,
        "Type": "mild"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: You can use aggregation pipeline and its `$subtract` operator: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/subtract/

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/ to use aggregation expressions in a find query. As a side note, having CurrentDate as a property of a document is quite unusual. Can't imagine a usecase where time flows differently for different documents.

Comment: @AlexBlex yeah the CurrentDate is misleading. Consider it a Date field that is definitely older than  that of the pharmacy. I'll change it if it makes things clearer.

Comment: So do you mean we need to find the pharmacies whose "EstablishedDate" is greater than "CurrentDate"?

Comment: No, I need the (CurrentDate - EstablishedDate) > 15. I'll update my question with this.

Comment: Your second document contains `CurrentDate` but first one does not?

Comment: Oops, my bad,  this is just a quick sample I wrote down, fixed it.

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50862096/convert-string-to-date-and-get-difference/50864332#50864332

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet In their case they are using only one date and comparing it with the Date() operation which returns the current Day's date, but I want it to be compared with the other date field present.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below aggregation

```
 db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$redact": {
      "$cond": [
        {
          "$lt": [
            {
              "$divide": [
                {
                  "$subtract": [
                    "$CurrentDate",
                    "$EstablishedDate"
                  ]
                },
                1000 * 60 * 60 * 24
              ]
            },
            365 * 15
          ]
        },
        "$$KEEP",
        "$$PRUNE"
      ]
    }
  }
])
```

Comment: yes this pretty much answers my question, I am using pipeline though, but I extracted the bits that were confusing me from here. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You can use date time operator [`$year`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/year/) to extract the year.

Something like

```
db.colname.find({"$expr":{
  "$gt":[
    {"$subtract":[
      {"$year":"$CurrentDate"},
      {"$year":"$EstablishedDate"}
    ]},
    15
  ]
}})
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check this aggregate query :

```
db.test.aggregate([
    {
    "$redact": {
        "$cond": [{
            "$gt": [{ 
                "$divide": [{
                    "$subtract": ["$CurrentDate", "$EstablishedDate"] },
                    1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 365
                ]},
            15
            ]},
            "$$KEEP",
            "$$PRUNE"
            ]
        }
    }
])
```

Here we are subtracting the `CurrentDate` and `EstablishedDate` and finding the difference between them in years. If it is greater than 15, only then we'll display them.

Try this & let me know if it worked for you.