# Incrementing a day to a Date in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

How can I increment a date by 7 days in a document without having to manually set the date?

```
Collection Data:
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e302f83edd1fd00125abbf9"),
    "dateTransferred" : 2020-01-26T00:00:00.000+00:00
}
```

I can easily update the collection by using:

```
db.data.updateMany(
  {},
  {
    "$set": { "dateTransferred": new ISODate("2020-02-03T03:34:54Z") }
  }
)
```

Is there a way I can update it dynamically (Similar to DateAdd)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, in MongoDB 4.2+ you can update it like this:

```
db.col.updateOne(
   { "_id": ObjectId("5e302f83edd1fd00125abbf9") },
   [
      { $set: { dateTransferred: { $add: ["$dateTransferred", 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24] } } }
   ]
)
```

Of course, if you like to update all documents then it would be

```
db.col.updateMany(
   {},
   [
      { $set: { dateTransferred: { $add: ["$dateTransferred", 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24] } } }
   ]
)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I tried using updateMany but it was giving me an error. Instead I used db.col.update() and added multi:true and it worked perfectly.  Thanks.

Comment: `updateMany()` is equal to `update(..., multi:true)`, most likely there is just a typo. Or your MongoDB is older than version 3.2.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can not access values of record that is being updated using this simple notation.

You might want to try using the aggregation pipeline (limited to mongodb 4.2+) as described here: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#update-with-aggregation-pipeline

So far, I haven't tried this myself, but looks promising ;-)

Comment: I just tried incrementing a date using $add in the aggregation pipeline and confirm it works.  See https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/add/#perform-addition-on-a-date for more details.