# MongoDB find all documents where field 1 is seven days or more after field 2

Tags: mongodb, robo3t

I need to search through a large mongo collection and find all the documents where updatedAt is at least 7 days after createdAt.

My data looks basically like this:

```
"createdAt" : ISODate("2021-04-03T10:17:21.256Z"),
"updatedAt" : ISODate("2021-04-03T10:17:21.256Z")
```

I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`$expr`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/) in match. [`$dateAdd`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateAdd/) is only available in mongodb 5.0.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      $expr: {
        $gt: [
          "$updatedAt",
          {
            $dateAdd: {
              startDate: "$createdAt",
              unit: "day",
              amount: 7
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/gOpd9b1689Z)

---

Use [`$expr`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/) in match. [`$add`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30996728/adding-subtracting-days-to-isodate-in-mongodb-shell) .

604800000 = 7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      $expr: {
        $gt: [
          "$updatedAt",
          {
            $add: [
              "$createdAt",
              604800000
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/TwV2N2pd8M3)

---

use [`$where`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/where/)

```
db.collection.find({
  "$where": "this.updatedAt > new Date(this.createdAt.getTime() + 604800000)"
})
```

[mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/nPzEvKu2b36)

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.  It looks like we use an older version of Mongo so I'll see what I can do based on your answer.  I appreciate it.

Comment: @jrdhawk I update my answer with `$add`

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I'm still having some trouble. It looks  like we use Mongo 3.6.0.  I keep getting:

Failed to execute script.

Error:
Uncaught exception: Error: command failed: { "ok" : 0, "code" : 303, "errmsg" : "Feature not supported" } : aggregate failed :
_getErrorWithCode@src/mongo/shell/utils.js:25:13

Comment: @jrdhawk I think [`$expr`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.2/reference/operator/query/expr/) and with `$gt` and `$add` are available in mongodb 3.6

Comment: @jrdhawk I update my answer with [`$where`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/where/)

Comment: So I just found out all our databases are mongo except this one and it's DocumentDB.  I'm sure all your answers would have worked had I been querying Mongo like I thought.  Sorry for my mistake and thanks for taking the time.  I will still use these with Mongo.

Comment: @jrdhawk accept this answer since it really solve your original problem,

Comment: Or even use `db.collection.find`. [mongoplayground.net](https://mongoplayground.net/p/HL7MopDuToI)

Comment: @YuTing  Again thanks for your info.  I think the main problem is DocumentDB isn't compatible with $expr or $where according to the docs https://docs.aws.amazon.com/documentdb/latest/developerguide/mongo-apis.html#mongo-apis-query