# MongoDB conditional querying using ISODate

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I would like to know how to query based on below condition in MongoDB.
let's say I have a field in a collection called `created_at` and it is `ISODate()` now I want to get all the data like `ISODate() + 1 Hour` greater than `current time`. how do I do that ? I tried searching the web. I don't understand how to search.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("55c48b37f09e091c1100002a"),
    "user_id" : 1,
    "flagged" : 0,
    "flag_count" : 0,
    "likes" : [ 
        1, 
        3, 
        7
    ],
    "dislikes" : [],
    "img_url" : "something :D",
    "place_id" : "55ba017ef09e098c1500002d",
    "updated_at" : ISODate("2015-08-28T09:30:44.000Z"),
    "created_at" : ISODate("2015-08-07T10:40:55.000Z"),
    "moderated" : true
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18233945/query-to-get-last-x-minutes-data-with-mongodb That would make db.[yourcollection].find({created_at: {$gt: new Date(ISODate().getTime() - 1000 * 3600 * 1)}});

Comment: @piscator thank you :) it worked. there is an additional problem. I am running it in PHP. let me sort it out.

Answer (score 0):

Create a IsoDate with one hour less and use $gt

Comment: No, It cannot be done because, 1 hour is not a constant variable. It can be changed to several hours.

Comment: db.collection.find( { created_at: { $gt: ISODate("2015-08-07T9:40:55.000Z")} } ) should match your document

Comment: It was an example for structure. Let me explain more. 

a user post something on 24.09.2015 I put the interval as 24 hours. now it has to filtered in my query if it is 24 hours older.

Comment: You have to create a Date object that has x hours less than the current date. And then put it into you query.