# Finding Documents created today

Tags: mongodb, meteor

So, In meteor, I am trying to count the number of documents created today. Obviouly the code below tries to match it to the time of the day along with the date.

```
var ct2 =  Bids.find({$and:[{bidder:currentUser},{createdAt:Date()}]}).count();
```

How do I go about finding the number of documents for today ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might need to do something like this

[Query to get last X minutes data with Mongodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18233945/query-to-get-last-x-minutes-data-with-mongodb)

```
var ct2 =  Bids.find({
    $and: [
       { bidder: currentUser },
       {
           createdAt: { $gt: new Date(Date.now() - (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) }
       }
    ]
}).count();
```

Comment: ISODate not defined.

Comment: Can you try with `Date.now()` instead of `ISODate().getTime()` and see. Basically you need to get current time in milliseconds and remove last 24 hours from it.

Comment: Nice to know that it worked. Can you accept it as answer.

Answer (score 1):

By using moment js:

```
date=moment().add(-1,'days').toISOString();
val1 = checkdate1.substring(0, 11)
temp=val1+'23:59:59.'
val3=date.substring(20,25)
val4=temp+val3;
count = Bids.find({"createdAt": {$gt:new Date(val4)}}).count()
```