# mongodb difference in time

Tags: mongodb, datetime, pymongo

How can i filter database entries that have a datetime less than 60min in the past?

I tried some date operations as follows in mongodb with two fields timestamp and marketstartime that are of type date in all my documents:

`{"$subtract": ["$timestamp", "$marketstartime"]}`

but it returns always null for that operation. Why?

My timestamp and marketstartime entries in the db are in date type and look as follows, this should be correct:
`2017-12-23 12:00:00.000Z`

The actual question I’m trying to solve: How can I get all entries that have a timestamp less than 60 min in the past from now?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find objects between two dates MongoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2943222/find-objects-between-two-dates-mongodb)

Comment: No, it is not a duplicate. Please read the question more carefully. Thanks

Comment: Vote retracted. Sorry, I didn't realize it was time difference between two date fields. Try adding sample document from your collection and your complete query. $subtract should give you difference in milliseconds.

Comment: I think this is the duplicate you're looking for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18233945/query-to-get-last-x-minutes-data-with-mongodb. You need to use a programatic way of now - x, whether that's in the mongo shell or the pymongo application.

Comment: The $subtract operator seems to work for me.
db.getCollection('data').aggregate([{$project: {d1: {$subtract: ["$date1", "$date2"]}}}])

Could you add the query which didn't work for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A query can composed for documents with `timestamp` value set less than 60 minutes ago.

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

query = {
    '$timestamp': {
        '$lt': datetime.now() + timedelta(minutes=-60)
    }
}

cursor = db.collection.find(query)
```