# MongoDB: Get list of newly added users in last five minutes

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

So I have a collection in which I dump logs.Each log have EndUserId field.
The mongoose schema is as follows:

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var ChatbotLogsSchema = new Schema({

    EndUserId: {
        type: String
    },
    MessageType: {
        type: String
    },
    Message:{
        type: String
    },
    CreatedDateTime: {
        type: Date, default: Date.now
    },
    UpdatedDateTime: {
        type: Date, default: Date.now
    },
    SentimentScore: {
        type: Number
    },
    EngageWeight: {
        type: Number
    }
}, { timestamps: { createdAt: 'CreatedDateTime',updatedAt:"UpdatedDateTime" } },{ collection: "ChatbotLogs" });
```

I want to get list of distinct `EndUserId` which are logged in last 5 minutes and were not present in collection previously.

What will be the efficient way to achieve this?

Edit :This question is different than [Query to get last X minutes data with Mongodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18233945/query-to-get-last-x-minutes-data-with-mongodb)
As I want to get only new users which were not present previously in collection.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Query to get last X minutes data with Mongodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18233945/query-to-get-last-x-minutes-data-with-mongodb)

Comment: "were not present in the collection previously." Do you mean that user logged in for the first time?

Comment: @Thamaraiselvam Yes. That's exactly I mean.

Comment: `Mongoose.distinct` with conditions did not work?

Comment: @Thamaraiselvam it works but it doesn't tell me if its a new user. Combination of more than one query may get me a solution but i just want to know if there any efficient way to do this