# Add minutes to while loop

Tags: javascript, while-loop

I am trying to make from the users End time add 30 mintues on an and on an on and display time

```
 function() {

            var toTime = new Date(result2);

            while (true) {

                var toTime30 = new Date(toTime.getTime() + toTime.getTimezoneOffset() *30 * 1000);
                var toTime60 = new Date(toTime30.getTime() + 30 * 60 * 1000);

                var addMin = toTime30 + "" + toTime60;


                    alert(addMin);
                    break;

            }
```

Right now the code only adds first for ex 02:00 to 02:30 how could i do so it keeps adding 30 minutes to the time?

## UPDATE

```
  var toTime = new Date(result2);

            while (true) {

                var iCount = 0;
                var toTime30 = new Date(toTime.getTime() + toTime.getTimezoneOffset() *30 * 1000);
                var toTime60 = new Date(toTime30.getTime() + 30 * 60 * 1000);

                var addMin = toTime30 + "" + toTime60 + (++iCount);


                alert(addMin);
                break;
            }
```

Comment: Are you writing the program in java?

Comment: I think your question is already answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1197928/how-to-add-30-minutes-to-a-javascript-date-object

Comment: you can use like this i think : *new Date(toTime.getTime() + 30 * 60 * 1000)*

Answer (score 0):

you cannot use variable before initialization. you should do something like

```
var iCount = 0;
var t = new Date();
var toTime30 = new Date(t.getTime() + t.getTimezoneOffset() * 30 * 1000);
console.log(t.getTime() + " - " + toTime30.getTime() + " - " +  (iCount++));

.> "1417509086906 - 1417505486906 - 0"
```

Comment: i already have them    var fromTime = new Date(result);
        var toTime = new Date(result2);

Comment: again you have toTime undefined

Comment: "1417509086906 - 1417505486906 - 0" this is not a valid datetime? how should use existing time and add 30 minutes?

Comment: getTime Return the number of milliseconds since 1970/01/01. You could replace it with your code - console.log(t + " - " + toTime30 + " - " +  (++iCount)); - and will get "Tue Dec 02 2014 10:58:48 GMT+0200 (FLE Standard Time) - Tue Dec 02 2014 09:58:48 GMT+0200 (FLE Standard Time) - 1"

Comment: doing like that i dont see any changes the loop still stops, i  will update my code in the top