# How to show hh:mm:ss format at y-axis with c3?

Tags: javascript, datetime, d3.js, datetime-format, c3.js

This is my dataset:

```
x: '2014-01-01', '2014-02-02', '2014-03-02', ...
y: '01:30:00', '00:55:00', '01:45:50', ...
```

I would like to show this data on my chart, using the [c3.js](http://c3js.org/) library.

I tried this so far (already converted time to seconds):

```
var chart = c3.generate({
    data : {
        x : 'x',
        columns : [
            ['x', '2010-01-01', '2011-01-01', '2012-01-01', '2013-01-01', '2014-01-01', '2015-01-01'],
            ['sample', 30, 200, 100, 400, 150, 250]
        ]
    },
    axis : {
        x : {
            type: 'timeseries'
        },
        y : {
            tick : {
                format: d3.time.format("%X")
                //or format: function (d) { return '$' + d; }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I would do, is this :

1. Create a new date that has time `00:00:00` :

   `date = new Date('01-01-2016 00:00:00')`
2. Turn that date into a timestamp :

   `timestamp = date.getTime()`
3. Add Y seconds to that timestamp :

   `timestamp = timestamp + (y * 1000)`
4. Create a new date, using that value as input :

   `date = new Date(timestamp)`
5. Use `d3.time.format` to format that date accordingly :

   `time = d3.time.format("%H:%M:%S")(date)`
6. Put all the pieces together and turn it into a oneliner :

   `time = d3.time.format("%H:%M:%S")(new Date(new Date('01-01-2016 00:00:00').getTime() + (y * 1000)));`

Now, you can just put this oneliner into a `format` function for your Y-axis and return `time` :

```
var chart = c3.generate({
    data : {
        x : 'x',
        columns : [
            ['x', '2010-01-01', '2011-01-01', '2012-01-01', '2013-01-01', '2014-01-01', '2015-01-01'],
            ['sample', 30, 200, 100, 400, 150, 250]
        ]
    },
    axis : {
        x : {
            type: 'timeseries'
        },
        y : {
            tick : {
                format : function (y) {
                    return d3.time.format("%H:%M:%S")(new Date(new Date('01-01-2016 00:00:00').getTime() + (y * 1000)));
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

See [**this Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/0h8sh7am/8/) for a demo.

---

#### More info :

- [**How to use D3's `d3.time.format`**](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Time-Formatting)
- [**How to use c3.js's tick format**](http://c3js.org/reference.html#axis-x-tick-format)
- [**How to add a certain number of seconds to a JavaScript Date object?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1197928/how-to-add-30-minutes-to-a-javascript-date-object)

Comment: I tried this without success. Could you fork my jsfiddle: [http://jsfiddle.net/0h8sh7am/5/](http://jsfiddle.net/0h8sh7am/5/)

Comment: Thanks, but the problem is that I want my y-axis to be time format and thats currently not supported by c3. So I need a workaround.

Comment: Cool, there seems to be a way, but your fiddle shows the local time. The `sample` data are seconds and this should be converted to `hh:mm:ss`.

Comment: You are my hero of the day!

Comment: @Julian : You're welcome. I just updated my answer again. Anyway, I love this kind of fiddling around with code, so it truly was my pleasure ;-)

Answer (score 1):

To also get this work with Firefox you need to set:

```
Fri Jan 01 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (CET)
```

instead of

```
01-01-2016 00:00:00
```