# How to determine the date of an "X minutes from now" event

Tags: javascript, date, time

I have a function that gives me a number, represents **minutes**. I will use minutes to trigger an up-coming event. I want to know when the event is going to be triggered. I would like to get the exact date of the trigger in a way similar to this:

- **2016-09-06 15:47:38** (years-months-days) (hours-minutes-seconds)

I wasn't able to find a thread that relates to this exact type of getting-future-data (minutes). Can someone help me with getting this done? Would be really grateful.

Comment: Have you tried anything? Did you look anywhere *other* than SO?

Comment: Of course. And I have tryed. I had previously created a timer function (for a countdown timer) but in that I didn't have to convert more than minutes/seconds...

Comment: Does this article help?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1197928/how-to-add-30-minutes-to-a-javascript-date-object

Comment: @J.Schmale yeah, quite a lot ^^ thank you

Comment: '2016-09-06 15:47:38' has no time zone, so likely represents a different moment in time depending on the time zone it's assumed to belong to (though some timezones have the same offset as others), and hence may be a different date too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use momentjs and its add method:

```js
var minutes = 28332832;
console.log(moment().add(minutes, 'minutes').format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.14.1/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

A plain javascript solution that uses a timestamp as milliseconds since 1970-01-01 (the epoch):

```
new Date(Date.now() + minutes*60*1000).toLocaleString()
```

If the format is not as required you can get year, month, day and so on and build your string on your own.

An alternative solution is to use the library [moment. js](http://momentjs.com/).

Comment: Not so much "the" timestamp but "a" timestamp. A timestamp is just something that represents a date and time e.g. '2016-02-29T23:41:016Z' is a timestamp, see [*Date and Time on the Internet: Timestamps*](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3339).

Comment: It's changed, now: "the timestamp" - > "a timestamp".

Answer (score 1):

you could use [momentJS](http://momentjs.com/) to make a momentObject of your date, and then use the .add() function to add any interval.
For exemple

```
moment('2016-09-06 15:47:38', 'YYYY-MM-DD H:i:s').add('minutes', 5);
```

I'm not sure about the format in the first method but this should work.
if not, you can check on [The official MomentJS Documentation](http://momentjs.com/docs/) for parsing format and more.
Hopes it helps !

- Nic