# How to set time with AM PM in Javascript Date Object

Tags: javascript

Say that I have DateTime in this format `Fri Feb 02 2018 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (IST)`

And from the time picker plugin getting the time `1:10am` or `2:30pm` in this format.

I am not sure how to calculate and combine/add them both to produce this result:
`Fri Feb 02 2018 01:10:00 GMT+0530 (IST)` or `Fri Feb 02 2018 14:30:00 GMT+0530 (IST)`

I wish if there was something to do as simple as this:
`new Date(dateString).setHours(1:10am)`

Comment: Try this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8888491/how-do-you-display-javascript-datetime-in-12-hour-am-pm-format

Comment: `And from the time picker plugin`  what time picker plugin.

Comment: If the time is pm, just calculate like this: 12+yourTime (12+2:30 = 14:30)

Comment: @Keith I am using vuetifyjs's time picker plugin https://vuetifyjs.com/components/pickers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seems like you need to parse it on your own:

```
function parseDaytime(time) {
  let [hours, minutes] = time.substr(0, time.length  -2).split(":").map(Number);
  if (time.includes("pm") && hours !== 12) hours += 12;
  return 1000/*ms*/ * 60/*s*/ * (hours * 60 + minutes);
}
```

To add it to a date:

```
new Date(
  +new Date("Fri Feb 02 2018 00:00:00 GMT+0530")
  +parseDaytime("1:20pm")
);
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a simple function to do what your after.

It basically splits the time using a regex, and then calls setHours & setMins, adding 12 hours if pm is selected.

The example below takes the current datetime, and sets 1:10am & 2:40pm..

```js
function setHours(dt, h) {
  var s = /(\d+):(\d+)(.+)/.exec(h);
  dt.setHours(s[3] === "pm" ? 
    12 + parseInt(s[1], 10) : 
    parseInt(s[1], 10));
  dt.setMinutes(parseInt(s[2],10));
}

var d = new Date();
console.log(d);
setHours(d, "1:10am");
console.log(d);
setHours(d, "2:40pm");
console.log(d);
```

Comment: Well, 12AM is 00. This does not work for that case.

Comment: @CanserYanbakan  AM / PM is one of those locale oddities, I'm in the UK and it's `0:00 am` & `0:00 pm` , eg. -> `console.log(new Date('2020-01-01').toLocaleString('en-GB', { hour: 'numeric', minute: 'numeric', hour12: true }));`  = `0:00 am`  But yes, if your from another country then you might want to alter accordingly.   Or to be fair there might be some better alternative now, as this was written over 5 years ago now..

Answer (score 1):

You can parse the time string into hours & minutes, adjust the hours according to am/pm & set it to the date object then:

```
var dateString = 'Fri Feb 02 2018 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (IST)';
var hoursString = '2:30pm';
var parts = hoursString.replace(/am|pm/, '').split(':')
var hours = parseInt(parts[0]) + (hoursString.indexOf('pm') !== -1 ? 12 : 0);
var minutes = parts[1];
var date = new Date(dateString);
date.setUTCHours(hours, minutes);
console.log(date); // in your local time
console.log(date.toUTCString()); // in UTC (i.e. without timezone offset)
```

(Note setHours / setUTCHours mutates date object but returns unix timestamp of the updated datetime.)

Comment: thanks for your help, the output was suppose to be `Fri Feb 02 2018 14:30:00 GMT+0530 (IST)` but getting `Thu Feb 01 2018 20:00:00 GMT+0530 (IST)`

Comment: You are getting the result with your timezone offset (14:30 + 05:30 = 20:00), getting UTC value should be done with `date.getUTCString()` resp. `utcDate = new Date(date.getUTCString());` (edited the answer)