# Add minutes to specific time in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, time

i want to add 1010 minutes to my time: `12 am`. the final time should be: `4:50 pm`. The date should NOT matter.

i tried with this:

```
function AddMinutesToDate(date, minutes) {
  return new Date(date.getTime() + minutes*60000);
}

alert(AddMinutesToDate(2017-06-16), 1010)
```

but it did not work. please help? thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add 30 minutes to a JavaScript Date object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1197928/how-to-add-30-minutes-to-a-javascript-date-object)

Comment: 2017-06-16 isn't a date object or a string.

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp

Comment: "*…but it did not work*" is not helpful. What result did you get? What error messages were in the console? What result did you expect?

Comment: People not responding to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like that : (sorry Will I can't edit your code because the change is less than 6 characters...)

```js
function AddMinutesToDate(date, minutes) {
  return new Date(new Date(date).getTime() + minutes * 60000);
}   

alert(AddMinutesToDate('2017-06-16', 1010));
```

Comment: `new Date('2017-06-16')` will be treated as UTC, likely the OP wants local.

Answer (score 1):

This function will accept ISO format and also receives minutes as parameter.

```js
function addSomeMinutesToTime(startTime, minutestoAdd) {
  const dateObj = new Date(startTime);
  const newDateInNumber = dateObj.setMinutes(dateObj.getMinutes() + minutestoAdd);
  const processedTime = new Date(newDateInNumber).toISOString();
  console.log(processedTime)
  return processedTime;
}
addSomeMinutesToTime(("2019-08-06T10:28:10.687Z"), 1010 )
```

Answer (score 0):

You were pretty close. Just a couple of errors.

```js
function AddMinutesToDate(date, minutes) {
  return new Date(new Date().getTime() + minutes * 60000);
}

alert(AddMinutesToDate('2017-06-16', 1010));
```

Comment: You're not using the date parameter