# How to add, increment native Time variables in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, datetime, momentjs, timespan

**How to add time (both Hours & Mins) dynamically & repetitively in Javascript to auto increment date object correctly**, some times I'm adding mins, or hours, or HH & mm - I want to get the new totaled time and have it return correctly incre/decremented valid time/date object.

For e.g. while adding all the hours across table rows/grids, (the duration/time being added is not known ahead of time, we dont know if its just adding mins, or hours and mins or days or increment or decremented, look at the C# call, it handles the time math correctly) some cells have mins, others have HH:mm. The [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1197928/how-to-add-30-minutes-to-a-javascript-date-object/22515961?noredirect=1#comment82991412_22515961) on SO *dont address incrementing, or add constant time, or add previously known fragments of the time*, like adding 30 mins or don't factor dynamics times, or moving the date forward or backwards (if negative time/deductions).

So far I've been doing this manually and missing many use-cases, 
`var newDateObj = new Date(oldDateObj.getTime() + diff*60000);`

for e.g how can I do this/dynamically, and have the `newDateObj` correctly *auto increment hours, or days* etc.

```
var newDateObj = (oldDateObj) + AddMinsTimeObj; // AddTimeObj is mins here
var newDateObj = (oldDateObj) + AddHoursTimeObj; // 2Hrs hours here
var newDateObj = (oldDateObj) + AddHoursMinsTimeObj; // Add 1:40 here
var newDateObj = (oldDateObj) + AddDaysHoursMinsTimeObj; // Add days hours mins
```

---

in other langs, java, C# you can just add time, dates, time spans, `System.DateTime addDynamicTimeOrDuration = today.Add(duration);` where duration can feedin `1hr:30` mins, or `220 mins` etc. How to do the same in Javascript.

---

**Update 1:** Many have suggested I use the momentjs `duration`, however from the link momentjs [does not have the function](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/subtract/) & this link it shows [you **cannot** create duration from 2 datetime objects](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/creating/) either by subtraction or create!

---

**Update2:**

I am trying this.. getting closer

`moment().add($this.val + moment().diff(date1, date1))`;

---

I simply want **to be able to add time to time & get the correct answer from a function**, (regardless of whats passed in, i.e. mins, hours or days). I feel like this should have been easier/handled by a function, and let it decide whats inside each `datetime` obj and then add them together. (Why is this so hard in js? and not part of the base lib.)

Comment: Dates and times in js is quite unpleasant to work with, i would look into something like [`moment.js`](https://momentjs.com/) if i were you.

Comment: @Olian04 yes I am finding that out, doing it on my own is giving me a lot of headaches. So, I want something to simply add two time correctly in JS, _my challenge with momentjs is you have to specify ahead of time, which I wont know always, if the user entered days or hours_, for e.g. `moment('November 1977').fromNow()`
// '34 years ago' its a lot of rewrite to parse out, and error prone.

`moment().add('days', 2).calendar();
// 'Monday at 8:30 AM'` - here it requires I know I am adding days ahead of time!!

Comment: I'm not sure I understand you. What do you mean by `here it requires I know I am adding days ahead of time`?

Comment: but how can you possibly do the calculation if you don't know what you're adding?

Comment: @GiacomoCosimato I am adding dateTime variables from a input box, `the fragements of which part of the time is not know` for e.g, I dont know if I am adding just mins or hours & mins ahead of time. The user could have typed just secs, or hours or mins.

Comment: the previous SO samples, js code is very specific to adding mins, or hours, I want it to be able to handle all three and not worry about it.

Comment: ok, but at some point you do know what you've got, right? So you should be able to use a library or whatever other method.

Comment: You can `moment().add(Duration)` where `Duration` is a special moment object that can be seconds, minutes, days, whatever. https://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/

Comment: I strongly recommend moment.js here.

Comment: anyway, a simple solution would be to convert everything to milliseconds and then do the sum.

Comment: @ChrisRiebschlager that what I was looking for awesome. I dont see how to extract duration form two dateobjects from that help page, _can you please tell me if a user enters some time, using that `userEnterTimeObject` and `myDateObj` how can I pass a couple date objects to it and get the duration_, so that I may add it to back to another date?

Comment: @GiacomoCosimato thats actually a good idea and I have been limping by with it, how however I am not able to handle some cases like increments/decrements to next day. I guess that should be two separate functions, I was hoping there was func/lib out there.

Comment: what do you mean? If you convert everything to milliseconds, you can work with unix timestamps. You get the initial timestamp with `getTime`, then if you want to add a day, you sum the duration of a day in ms.
`new Date().getTime() + 8.64e+7;`

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you can create a duration based on the milliseconds produced by moment's `diff` function on those two dates. https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/difference/ But at that point, you don't really need a duration. You could just `moment.add()` those milliseconds.

Comment: @ChrisRiebschlager I was looking at `duration create, subtraction & add` functions. I am not sure why diff and subtraction are posted as different items, I see `diff` _as a subset of `subtractive` functions_. I'm testing this and the other options now, if you can post the date diff date sample I can mark as answer thanks.

Comment: @GiacomoCosimato after reading your comment, I looked up unix timestamps. Looks like if I have to specifically mention the unix time format in windows and then it might work. let me try to test this if it will work for me,

Comment: I think you can use [`moment().add(Duration)`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/add/) as already suggested. Can you provide sample values of `AddMinsTimeObj`, `AddHoursTimeObj` etc? Providing a MVCE is the best way to get a good working solution.

Comment: @VincenzoC the sample code is listed above, i simply want to be able to add time to time & get the correct answer from a function, (regardless of whats passed in, i.e. mins, hours or days). I feel like this should have been handled by a function, and let it decide whats inside each `datetime` obj and then add them together.

Comment: @transformer I asked for sample *values* of `AddMinsTimeObj`, `AddHoursTimeObj` etc. How does your _datetime obj_ look like? Moment can parse ISO 8601 duration (e.g. `P1Y2M3DT4H5M6S`) and strings like `7 23:59:59.999`.

Comment: @VincenzoC ok I understand now :)  strings from datetime objects `08:22` sometimes  `08` *.* `22` or just  `0822` or `22`. for all practical purposes my input assumes they are entering hours worked... this is the reason why I am trying to find an easy way to manage those diff inputs and add the time through a lib/function. In my case, the user never enters dates, just the hours and mins in the input box ( a numeric text box, that does not exceed 24 HH:MM) in .5 steps/increments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Moment.js, you can find the difference in milliseconds between any two date objects.

```
let birthday = moment([1978,7,12]);
let ageInMs = moment().diff(birthday);
```

That will give you a number of milliseconds between those two Moment objects. You don't need to know how many seconds, minutes, hours or day are contained within to do some Moment math.

```
let doubleMyAge = moment().add(ageInMs, 'ms');
```

The result will be a Moment object that is my current age into the future, i.e. a very long time from now.

Comment: Chris from your link I was trying to chain this with two arguments in a function, I was trying something like this in a function, `moment().add($this.val + moment().diff(date1, date1))`

Comment: `diff` doesn't quite work that way. You call it on a moment object instead of sending it two parameters. so it'd be more like `date1.diff(date2)` if `date1` and `date2` are both moment objects.

Comment: i simply want to be _able to add time to time_ & get the correct answer from a function, (regardless of whats passed in, i.e. mins, hours or days). I feel like this should have been handled by a function, and let it workout whats inside each `datetime obj` and then add them together.