# How to add 24 hr format into total hours in javascript

Tags: javascript, time, momentjs, addition, hour

How can I add 24:00 time format into total time in javascript?

```
var time1 = 12:10;
var time2 = 23:40;
```

Result

```
var totalTime = 35:50
```

I tried momentjs using duration but i can't format it :(

Comment: Show some code whatever you tried. @KIt

Comment: What is the expected output?

Answer (score 0):

Use add method from moment

```
moment().add(24, 'hours')
```

Answer (score 0):

Use moment, it is very easy https://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/add/

```
//With add
var moment = require('moment');
var time1 = '12:10' //String
var mtime1 = new moment(time1, 'HH:mm'); //Moment object

moment(mtime1).add(2, 'hours').format('HH:mm'); // 14:10
moment(mtime1).add(2, 'hours').hours(); // 14

//Same result with duration
var duration = moment.duration({'hours' : 2});

moment(mtime1).add(duration).format('HH:mm'); // 14:10
moment(mtime1).add(duration).hours(); // 14
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use vanilla javascript instead of a Library, you can refer to the following post: [How to add 30 minutes to a JavaScript Date object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1197928/how-to-add-30-minutes-to-a-javascript-date-object)

**VANILLA JAVASCRIPT**

You can use the following code:

```
function addMinutes(date, minutes) {
    return new Date(date.getTime() + minutes*60000);
}
```

And then you can use add the 24 hours as you wanted:

```
addMinutes(new Date('2014-11-02'), 60*24);
```

Please note that you will have a Date object, so you should format by yourself if you want it to be printed nicely.