# Angular / Ionic: Adding 'x' minutes into my start time

Tags: javascript

I would like to add 15 minutes into my starttime. However, how can I extract my datetime data for me to add?

"date":"2018-02-26T10:30:00Z" this is my start time. I would like to add to create my end time

Thankyou.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1197928/how-to-add-30-minutes-to-a-javascript-date-object

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add 30 minutes to a JavaScript Date object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1197928/how-to-add-30-minutes-to-a-javascript-date-object)