# Adding 50 minutes to Date()

Tags: javascript, date

What I'm trying to do is to add 50 minutes to the current date I get, so I want to get the date and then get the time and then add 50 minutes. I want to check if I'm doing it the right way:

```
d = new Date();
dateAfter50min = d.setDate(d.getMinutes() + 50);
```

Comment: _"I want to check if I'm doing it the right way"_ - This can be checked in seconds with a simple `console.log()`

Comment: Yes, thank you :) I mean if there is a more proper way for doing this.

Comment: This might help: [How to add 30 minutes to a JavaScript Date object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1197928/how-to-add-30-minutes-to-a-javascript-date-object)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to create a new Date by adding minutes to an existing the date, you can get the time in milliseconds, and then add the minutes converted to milliseconds - minutes * 60 * 1000:

```js
const d = new Date();
const dateAfter50min = new Date(d.getTime() + 50 * 60 * 1000);

console.log(d);
console.log(dateAfter50min);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to just modify your current date object you can do it by following code

```js
var d = new Date();
console.log(d);
d.setMinutes(d.getMinutes() + 50);
console.log(d);
```

Comment: This is just exactly what the OP posted.