# JS: Date manipulation

Tags: javascript, date, time

Trying to add hours to a date without success..
Variables and code I have tried:

```js
const date = '2018-10-18';
const time = '20:35';
const timezn = 2;

let end = new Date(date);
const endTimeArray = _.split(time, ':', 2);
const endHours = parseInt(endTimeArray[0]);
const endMinutes = parseInt(endTimeArray[1]);
end.setHours(end.getHours() + endHours - timezn);
end.setMinutes(end.getMinutes() + endMinutes);
const result = end.toLocaleTimeString();
console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.js"></script>
```

Expected result:

```
"2018-10-18T20:35:00.000+02:00"
```

Comment: Please update the snippet I made with the relevant library - it was not lodash as I thought - also you are missing timezn. What is wrong with  `time.split(':');`

Comment: Nothing wrong with JS's split but since I am using lodash, I want to use it everywher

Comment: Please add timezn to the snippet

Comment: it's just const timezone = 2; or timezone = 3; i.o GMT+2/GMT+3

Comment: UPDATE and then show expected and actual result. `"2018-10-18T20:35:00.000+02:00"` is certainly not a localTimeString

Comment: Don't you want `end.setMinutes(end.getMinutes() + endMinutes + hoursToAdd);` ???

Comment: It seems you're attempting to set the local time to 20:35. Parse the date as local, then just do `date.setHours(20, 35,0,0)` (note that '2018-10-18' will be parsed as UTC).

Answer (score 0):

This question has already been asked, and answered, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1197928/how-to-add-30-minutes-to-a-javascript-date-object) (see user KIP)

However, for your example, the following should do.

```
let end = new Date(date);
let newEnd = addMinutes(end, 60);

function addMinutes(date, minutes) {
    return new Date(date.getTime() + minutes*60000);
}
```

Comment: So, I tried to set date="18.10.2018" time="20:35", however the result with your example is Start Thu Oct 18 2018 23:00:00 GMT+0300 (Eastern European Summer Time)

Comment: end = addMinutes(new Date('18.10.2018'), parseInt(hours) + parseInt(minutes/60));

Comment: @Alex Are you saying this is what worked for you?

Comment: I can't see anything to recommend that approach over `date.setMinutes(date.getMinutes() + minutes)`, particularly as this answer returns a new Date rather than modifying the an existing Date (which is what the OP is doing).