# How to add 30 minutes to a specified time (min & max time) in javascript

Tags: javascript

How to add 30 minutes to a specified time (min & max time) in javascript.For example: I have start time as 03:00 AM and end time as 05:00 PM and I need to add 30minutes from start time to end time.

Comment: What have you tried? We expect people to at least make an effort and post what they done so far. Also, a Google search of your title will help you no end, but funnily enough, that was a no effort question too, but got over 600 up-votes...

Comment: This seems like a really simple math problem.... What *exactly* are you having trouble figuring out?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add 30 minutes to a JavaScript Date object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1197928/how-to-add-30-minutes-to-a-javascript-date-object)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by spliting the Time

this is how it can be done

```
var startTime = '03:00 AM';
var newStartTime = startTime;
var endTime = '05:00 AM';
var minutes=0;
var hours=0;
var timeArray=[];
var ampm='';
var executing=true;
while(executing) {
    timeArray.push(newStartTime);
    minutes = Number(minutes) + 30;
    hours = newStartTime.split(' ')[0].split(':')[0]
    ampm= newStartTime.split(' ')[1];
    if(minutes > 59) {
        if(Number(hours) > 12) {
            ampm = newStartTime.split(' ')[1] == 'AM'?'PM':'AM';
            hours = '01';
        }
        else {
            hours = Number(hours) + 1;
            if(hours.toString().length ==1) {
                hours = '0' + hours;
            }
        }
        minutes = minutes - 60;
    }
    if(minutes.toString().length ==1) {
                minutes = '0' + minutes;
    }
    newStartTime = hours + ':' + minutes+' ' +ampm;
    if(Number(newStartTime.split(' ')[0].split(':')[0]) > Number(endTime.split(' ')[0].split(':')[0])){
        if(newStartTime.split(' ')[1] == endTime.split(' ')[1])
            executing = false;
    }
    else if(Number(newStartTime.split(' ')[0].split(':')[0]) == Number(endTime.split(' ')[0].split(':')[0])) {
         if(Number(newStartTime.split(' ')[0].split(':')[1]) >= Number(endTime.split(' ')[0].split(':')[1])) {
            if(newStartTime.split(' ')[1] == endTime.split(' ')[1])
                executing = false;
        }
    }
}
timeArray.push(endTime);
```

here is a small [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3n5uey7b/) for you

you can do the same with endTime,

there are many other ways to do this and this is one of those,

hope this solve your problem,

Comment: This works for adding 30 minutes to the time we are giving. But I am expecting like, if start time is 03:00AM and end time is 05:00PM, i need to get as 03:00AM, 03:30AM, 04:00AM, 04:30AM..........05:00PM.

Comment: so can you please explain me properly what do you actually wants

Comment: Sure. I have two time (start & end). I need to add 30 minutes each from start time till it reaches the end time. For example start time is 3:00Am and end time is 5:00PM. So I need an output as 3:00AM, 3:30AM, 4;00AM and till reaches 5:00PM. Hope you get it?