# Is there a way to get the date x days prior? (Date arithmetic)

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, reactjs

I am wondering if there is a way to get the date for example 63 days prior?
Only day, month and year is required, no hours, minutes and seconds.

I know that it is possible to do  Date object - Date object but I wondering if it is possible to date Date object (Date.now()) - an int (63),

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kip has left a thorough answer in [How to add 30 minutes to a JavaScript Date object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1197928/how-to-add-30-minutes-to-a-javascript-date-object).

You can do this to add or subtract days from a date by entering *diff* as a positive or negative number:

```
var newDateObj = new Date(oldDateObj.getTime() + diff*24*60*60000);
```

The 24*60*60000 stands for 24 hours * 60 minutes * 60 seconds to multiplies to the total milliseconds in a day.

Typically you do not want to do this because dates are complicated. Kip mentions that if a user is observing Daylight Savings, days deviate from 24 hours which will mess up your calculation.