# How to add 2 minutes in given time (HH:MM:SS) in Node?

Tags: javascript, node.js, time, momentjs

I have a time say for eg : 10:59:02 Now i need to add 2 minutes here & it should give me time as 11:01:02. I tried but was not able to achieve Can anyone help me with this ?

Comment: add your code here

Comment: Please add your code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add 30 minutes to a JavaScript Date object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1197928/how-to-add-30-minutes-to-a-javascript-date-object)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using moment library.

```js
var date = moment('10:59:02 PM', 'hh:mm:ss A')
    .add(2, 'minutes')
    .format("hh:mm:ss");
console.log(date);
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.7.0/moment.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Actually, you need to convert the time/date in Unix timestamp then you can add the minutes and then again pass that timestamp in Date constructor. you get the time as you needed.

```js
var unixTimestamp = Math.round(new Date("2019-05-22 15:10:00").getTime()/1000); // convert to unixtimestamp
console.log(unixTimestamp);

unixTimestamp += 120 // added 2 min
date = new Date(unixTimestamp * 1000); // again convert to date
console.log(date); // got your solution.
```

Comment: It's always a good practice to add some explanation to your answer alongside the code