# How to produce recurrence rschedule durations with timeshifts

Tags: javascript, rrule, moment-timezone

I am using [rSchedule](https://gitlab.com/john.carroll.p/rschedule) to produce working hour intervals.But timezone is ignored. How can I achieve it?

The input is working hour intervals in a day, with timezone as below.

```
const input = {
  workingHours:[{start:9, end:12}, {start:13, end:18}], 
  timeZone:'Europe/Berlin'
};
```

With the below code, I am expecting to produce intervals with respect to day light shiftings in a year. However, the produced output ignores the timeZone I provided.

```
import { Schedule } from "@rschedule/core/generators";
import '@rschedule/moment-tz-date-adapter/setup';
import moment from 'moment-timezone';

const schedule = new Schedule({
      rrules: [
        {
          frequency: "MONTHLY",//frequency: "WEEKLY",
          //byDayOfWeek: ["MO", 'TU', 'WE', 'TH', 'FR'],
          duration:1000 * 60 * 60 * 3,//input.workingHours[0].end-input.workingHours[0].start,
          byHourOfDay:[12],//input.workingHours[0].end
          timezone:'Europe/Berlin',//input.timeZone,

          start: moment(Date.UTC(2019, 0, 1)),
          end: moment(Date.UTC(2020, 0, 0))
        }
      ]
    });

    schedule.occurrences().toArray().forEach(adapter => {
      console.log(
          {
            start: adapter.date.toISOString(),
            end: adapter.end.toISOString(),
          }
        )
    })
```

Output ignoring timezone:

```
 { start: '2019-01-01T09:00:00.000Z', end: '2019-01-01T12:00:00.000Z' }
 { start: '2019-02-01T09:00:00.000Z', end: '2019-02-01T12:00:00.000Z' }
 { start: '2019-03-01T09:00:00.000Z', end: '2019-03-01T12:00:00.000Z' }
 { start: '2019-04-01T09:00:00.000Z', end: '2019-04-01T12:00:00.000Z' }
 { start: '2019-05-01T09:00:00.000Z', end: '2019-05-01T12:00:00.000Z' }
 { start: '2019-06-01T09:00:00.000Z', end: '2019-06-01T12:00:00.000Z' }
 { start: '2019-07-01T09:00:00.000Z', end: '2019-07-01T12:00:00.000Z' }
 { start: '2019-08-01T09:00:00.000Z', end: '2019-08-01T12:00:00.000Z' }
 { start: '2019-09-01T09:00:00.000Z', end: '2019-09-01T12:00:00.000Z' }
 { start: '2019-10-01T09:00:00.000Z', end: '2019-10-01T12:00:00.000Z' }
 { start: '2019-11-01T09:00:00.000Z', end: '2019-11-01T12:00:00.000Z' }
 { start: '2019-12-01T09:00:00.000Z', end: '2019-12-01T12:00:00.000Z' }
```

Expected output:

```
{ start: '2019-01-01T11:00:00.000Z', end: '2019-01-01T14:00:00.000Z' },
{ start: '2019-02-01T11:00:00.000Z', end: '2019-02-01T14:00:00.000Z' },
{ start: '2019-03-01T11:00:00.000Z', end: '2019-03-01T14:00:00.000Z' },
{ start: '2019-04-01T10:00:00.000Z', end: '2019-04-01T13:00:00.000Z' },
{ start: '2019-05-01T10:00:00.000Z', end: '2019-05-01T13:00:00.000Z' },
{ start: '2019-06-01T10:00:00.000Z', end: '2019-06-01T13:00:00.000Z' },
{ start: '2019-07-01T10:00:00.000Z', end: '2019-07-01T13:00:00.000Z' },
{ start: '2019-08-01T10:00:00.000Z', end: '2019-08-01T13:00:00.000Z' },
{ start: '2019-09-01T10:00:00.000Z', end: '2019-09-01T13:00:00.000Z' },
{ start: '2019-10-01T10:00:00.000Z', end: '2019-10-01T13:00:00.000Z' },
{ start: '2019-11-01T11:00:00.000Z', end: '2019-11-01T14:00:00.000Z' },
{ start: '2019-12-01T11:00:00.000Z', end: '2019-12-01T14:00:00.000Z' }
```

Comment: Because in moment you've not set the timezone. You are calling `moment` wuthout any tz set to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because I'm not familiar with these timezone's (and don't know what timezone the "expected output" is suppose to be in), it's a little unclear what you expect to happen. But as @JorgeFuentesGonzález pointed out in a comment, an issue is *probably* that you aren't providing the `start` datetime in the proper timezone.

As pointed out in the [rSchedule source code](https://gitlab.com/john.carroll.p/rschedule/blob/4d3af301dc859cee8f7118c28cfcfbbc3b36b8cd/packages/core/src/generators/rule.ts#L19-25) (which should conveniently show up as a tooltip in editors like VSCode--***edit** I've gone ahead and clarified this in the rSchedule docs as well*), the `timezone` config option for `Rule` objects does not change the timezone the rule is in, it changes the timezone the rule is *displayed* in. This distinction is important for the internal functioning of rSchedule, but I can see in this case it is unclear.

So your rule is generating occurrences in your local timezone (because `start: moment(Date.UTC(2019, 0, 1))` generates a local `moment`), and then those occurrences are being transformed into the `'Europe/Berlin'` timezone before being output. Except wait! That's not what's happening. This `Rule` is part of a `Schedule`, so it's the schedule's timezone which determines the output timezone of occurrences. The schedule appears to have no timezone (so it is in the local timezone). So I think the rule is in the local timezone, and the output dates are in the local timezone.

- *Note: console logging using `toISOString()` may be obfuscating the fact that your output dates are in your local timezone, rather than whatever timezone you expect.*

Depending on what you are trying to accomplish, I'd suggest something like the following:

```
import { Schedule } from "@rschedule/core/generators";
import '@rschedule/moment-tz-date-adapter/setup';
import moment from 'moment-timezone';

const schedule = new Schedule({
  rrules: [
    {
      frequency: "MONTHLY",//frequency: "WEEKLY",
      duration:1000 * 60 * 60 * 3,//input.workingHours[0].end-input.workingHours[0].start,
      byHourOfDay:[12],//input.workingHours[0].end
      start: moment.tz(Date.UTC(2019, 0, 1), 'Europe/Berlin'),
      end: moment.tz(Date.UTC(2020, 0, 0), 'Europe/Berlin')
    }
  ],
  timezone:'Europe/Berlin'
});
```

[Codesandbox demo here](https://codesandbox.io/s/rschedule-so-example-0uepy?fontsize=14&module=%2Fsrc%2Findex.ts).

Let me know if you're still not seeing what you expect.

Comment: Your suggestion worked, thanks @john. The output date is in UTC, since I used date.toISOString(). Just as a comment as an early user of the rschedule library, I saw an rschedule rule as an interface/contract to create recurrence dates(milliseconds since epoch) regardless of the output timezone. Because it is straightforward to change the output format and timezone with other libraries. So, I expected start and end to be again milliseconds since epoch and the timezone field to handle the time shifts while generating recurrences.

Comment: Milliseconds since epoch is the UTC timezone. If rSchedule only processed dates in UTC, it would ignore DST shifts.