# How to edit clock code in so minute hand changes at interval of 30

Tags: javascript, html, css, clock

I currently have a clock created from javascript, css, and html. I am trying to find away to edit the javascript so that if I add .5 or +30 to the html for timezone offset the minute hand will also adjust adding 30 minutes to the current position. I also would like for the hour hand to update when this +30 minute interval occurs so that when the minute hand reachs 60 the hour hand will adjust to the next hour as well. Thanks!

```js
class Clock {
  constructor(id) {
    this.timezone = parseInt(document.getElementById(id).dataset.timezone);

    if (this.isDST(new Date())) {
      this.timezone += 1;
    }

    this.handSeconds = document.querySelector(`#${id} .hand.seconds`);
    this.handMinutes = document.querySelector(`#${id} .hand.minutes`);
    this.handHours = document.querySelector(`#${id} .hand.hours`);

    this.getTime();
    this.cycle();
  }

  isDST(now) {
    const jan = new Date(now.getFullYear(), 0, 1);
    const jul = new Date(now.getFullYear(), 6, 1);
    const dst = Math.max(jan.getTimezoneOffset(), jul.getTimezoneOffset());

    return now.getTimezoneOffset() < dst;
  }

  draw(hours, minutes, seconds) {
    const drawSeconds = (seconds / 60) * 360 + 90;
    const drawMinutes = (minutes / 60) * 360 + 90;
    const drawHours = (hours / 12) * 360 + 90;

    this.handSeconds.style.transform = `rotate(${drawSeconds}deg)`;
    this.handMinutes.style.transform = `rotate(${drawMinutes}deg)`;
    this.handHours.style.transform = `rotate(${drawHours}deg)`;

    // fix for animation bump on when clock hands hit zero
    if (drawSeconds === 444 || drawSeconds === 90) {
      this.handSeconds.style.transition = "all 0s ease 0s";
    } else {
      this.handSeconds.style.transition =
        "all 0.05s cubic-bezier(0, 0, 0.52, 2.51) 0s";
    }
  }

  getTime() {
    const now = new Date();

    const hours = now.getUTCHours() + this.timezone;
    const minutes = now.getUTCMinutes();
    const seconds = now.getUTCSeconds();

    this.draw(hours, minutes, seconds);
  }

  cycle() {
    setInterval(this.getTime.bind(this), 1000);
  }
}

new Clock("okinawa");
new Clock("seattle");
new Clock("amalfi");
```

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #673AB7;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.content {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.content .widget {
  padding: 24px;
  margin: 24px;
}

.content .widget.clock {
  position: relative;
  width: 456px;
  height: 456px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: #5A2EA5;
}

.content .widget.clock#okinawa,
.content .widget.clock#amalfi {
  width: 240px;
  height: 240px;
}

.content .widget.clock#okinawa:before,
.content .widget.clock#amalfi:before {
  border-width: 3px;
}

.content .widget.clock#okinawa .hand,
.content .widget.clock#amalfi .hand {
  height: 3px;
  top: 118.5px;
  transform-origin: right 1.5px;
}

.content .widget.clock#okinawa .hand.seconds,
.content .widget.clock#amalfi .hand.seconds {
  display: yes;
}

.content .widget.clock:before {
  content: "";
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  border: 6px solid #FFF;
  border-radius: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.content .widget.clock .shadow {
  content: "";
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 100%);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform-origin: 50% 0%;
  opacity: 0.3;
  z-index: -1;
}

.content .widget.clock .hand {
  height: 6px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 225px;
  background-color: #FFF;
  border-radius: 100% 0% 0% 100%;
  transform-origin: right 3px;
  transition: all 0.05s cubic-bezier(0, 0, 0.52, 2.51) 0s;
}

.content .widget.clock .hand.seconds {
  width: 45%;
  left: 5%;
  opacity: 0.25;
}

.content .widget.clock .hand.minutes {
  width: 35%;
  left: 15%;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.content .widget.clock .hand.hours {
  width: 25%;
  left: 25%;
  opacity: 0.75;
}

.content .widget.clock .hand-cap {
  width: 5%;
  height: 5%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 47.5%;
  left: 47.5%;
  background-color: #FFF;
  border-radius: 100%;
}

.content .widget label {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: -24px;
  left: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: 200;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
  letter-spacing: 4px;
  color: #FFF;
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="widget clock" id="okinawa" data-timezone="+9">
    <div class="shadow"></div>
    <div class="hand seconds"></div>
    <div class="hand minutes"></div>
    <div class="hand hours"></div>
    <div class="hand-cap"></div>
    <label>Okinawa</label>
  </div>
  <div class="widget clock" id="seattle" data-timezone="-8">
    <div class="shadow"></div>
    <div class="hand seconds"></div>
    <div class="hand minutes"></div>
    <div class="hand hours"></div>
    <div class="hand-cap"></div>
    <label>Seattle</label>
  </div>
  <div class="widget clock" id="amalfi" data-timezone="+1">
    <div class="shadow"></div>
    <div class="hand seconds"></div>
    <div class="hand minutes"></div>
    <div class="hand hours"></div>
    <div class="hand-cap"></div>
    <label>Amalfi</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null`. Your selector is incorrect.Try  `\`#${id} .seconds\``

Comment: I had to remove the +30 from  `this.handSeconds = document.querySelector(\`#${id} .hand.seconds\` + 30);` - that is NOT where you want to do it - that is just wishful thinking

Comment: You want to change `const now = new Date();`

Comment: @mplungjan In what manner would I change it? Also is there away to just change the html next to the clock I want changed like how I did the offset for hours for this to be done?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1197928/how-to-add-30-minutes-to-a-javascript-date-object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mean like this?

1. get the time in hours and minutes if present

   ```
   this.timezone = document.getElementById(id).dataset.timezone;
   let [hh,mm] = this.timezone.slice(1).split("."); // remove the +/- before splitting
   this.timezoneMM = 60*hh +(mm ? parseInt(mm) : 0)

   this.timezoneMM *= this.timezone.indexOf("-")===0 ? -1:-1;
   ```
2. Add the minutes to the now object

   ```
   now.setMinutes(now.getMinutes()+this.timezoneMM)
   ```

   ```js
   class Clock {
     constructor(id) {
       this.timezone = document.getElementById(id).dataset.timezone;
       let [hh,mm] = this.timezone.slice(1).split("."); // remove the +/- before splitting
       this.timezoneMM = 60*hh +(mm ? parseInt(mm) : 0)
       
       this.timezoneMM *= this.timezone.indexOf("-")===0 ? -1:-1;
       
       if (this.isDST(new Date())) {
         this.timezone += 1;
       }

       this.handSeconds = document.querySelector(`#${id} .hand.seconds`);
       this.handMinutes = document.querySelector(`#${id} .hand.minutes`);
       this.handHours = document.querySelector(`#${id} .hand.hours`);

       this.getTime();
       this.cycle();
     }

     isDST(now) {
       const jan = new Date(now.getFullYear(), 0, 1);
       const jul = new Date(now.getFullYear(), 6, 1);
       const dst = Math.max(jan.getTimezoneOffset(), jul.getTimezoneOffset());

       return now.getTimezoneOffset() < dst;
     }

     draw(hours, minutes, seconds) {
       const drawSeconds = (seconds / 60) * 360 + 90;
       const drawMinutes = (minutes / 60) * 360 + 90;
       const drawHours = (hours / 12) * 360 + 90;

       this.handSeconds.style.transform = `rotate(${drawSeconds}deg)`;
       this.handMinutes.style.transform = `rotate(${drawMinutes}deg)`;
       this.handHours.style.transform = `rotate(${drawHours}deg)`;

       // fix for animation bump on when clock hands hit zero
       if (drawSeconds === 444 || drawSeconds === 90) {
         this.handSeconds.style.transition = "all 0s ease 0s";
       } else {
         this.handSeconds.style.transition =
           "all 0.05s cubic-bezier(0, 0, 0.52, 2.51) 0s";
       }
     }

     getTime() {
       const now = new Date();

       now.setMinutes(now.getMinutes()+this.timezoneMM)

       const hours = now.getUTCHours();
       const minutes = now.getUTCMinutes();
       const seconds = now.getUTCSeconds();

       this.draw(hours, minutes, seconds);
     }

     cycle() {
       setInterval(this.getTime.bind(this), 1000);
     }
   }

   new Clock("okinawa");
   new Clock("kolkata");
   new Clock("amalfi");
   ```

   ```css
   html {
     height: 100%;
     display: flex;
     justify-content: center;
     align-items: center;
     background-color: #673AB7;
     overflow: hidden;
   }

   .content {
     display: flex;
     align-items: center;
   }

   .content .widget {
     padding: 24px;
     margin: 24px;
   }

   .content .widget.clock {
     position: relative;
     width: 456px;
     height: 456px;
     border-radius: 100%;
     box-sizing: border-box;
     background-color: #5A2EA5;
   }

   .content .widget.clock#okinawa,
   .content .widget.clock#amalfi {
     width: 240px;
     height: 240px;
   }

   .content .widget.clock#okinawa:before,
   .content .widget.clock#amalfi:before {
     border-width: 3px;
   }

   .content .widget.clock#okinawa .hand,
   .content .widget.clock#amalfi .hand {
     height: 3px;
     top: 118.5px;
     transform-origin: right 1.5px;
   }

   .content .widget.clock#okinawa .hand.seconds,
   .content .widget.clock#amalfi .hand.seconds {
     display: none;
   }

   .content .widget.clock:before {
     content: "";
     width: 100%;
     height: 100%;
     position: absolute;
     top: 0;
     left: 0;
     border: 6px solid #FFF;
     border-radius: 100%;
     box-sizing: border-box;
   }

   .content .widget.clock .shadow {
     content: "";
     width: 100%;
     height: 500px;
     position: absolute;
     top: 50%;
     left: 0;
     background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 100%);
     transform: rotate(-45deg);
     transform-origin: 50% 0%;
     opacity: 0.3;
     z-index: -1;
   }

   .content .widget.clock .hand {
     height: 6px;
     position: absolute;
     top: 225px;
     background-color: #FFF;
     border-radius: 100% 0% 0% 100%;
     transform-origin: right 3px;
     transition: all 0.05s cubic-bezier(0, 0, 0.52, 2.51) 0s;
   }

   .content .widget.clock .hand.seconds {
     width: 45%;
     left: 5%;
     opacity: 0.25;
   }

   .content .widget.clock .hand.minutes {
     width: 35%;
     left: 15%;
     opacity: 0.5;
   }

   .content .widget.clock .hand.hours {
     width: 25%;
     left: 25%;
     opacity: 0.75;
   }

   .content .widget.clock .hand-cap {
     width: 5%;
     height: 5%;
     position: absolute;
     top: 47.5%;
     left: 47.5%;
     background-color: #FFF;
     border-radius: 100%;
   }

   .content .widget label {
     display: block;
     width: 100%;
     position: absolute;
     top: -24px;
     left: 0;
     font-family: sans-serif;
     font-weight: 200;
     font-size: 12px;
     text-transform: uppercase;
     text-align: center;
     letter-spacing: 4px;
     color: #FFF;
     opacity: 0.5;
   }
   ```

   ```html
   <div class="content">
     <div class="widget clock" id="okinawa" data-timezone="+9">
       <div class="shadow"></div>
       <div class="hand seconds"></div>
       <div class="hand minutes"></div>
       <div class="hand hours"></div>
       <div class="hand-cap"></div>
       <label>Okinawa</label>
     </div>
     <div class="widget clock" id="kolkata" data-timezone="+5.30">
       <div class="shadow"></div>
       <div class="hand seconds"></div>
       <div class="hand minutes"></div>
       <div class="hand hours"></div>
       <div class="hand-cap"></div>
       <label>Kolkata</label>
     </div>
     <div class="widget clock" id="amalfi" data-timezone="+1">
       <div class="shadow"></div>
       <div class="hand seconds"></div>
       <div class="hand minutes"></div>
       <div class="hand hours"></div>
       <div class="hand-cap"></div>
       <label>Amalfi</label>
     </div>
   </div>
   ```

Comment: What all did you change or add to get this outcome?

Comment: Also when the minute hand reaches 60 will it also affect the hour hand so that it changes as well?

Comment: @StackGuru I did not need to change the clock's behaviour. The hour hand moves when needed