# How can I add time to datetime using Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have two variables here (datetime and time)

And I want to add the time to the datetime variable.

```
var datetime = '2020/09/21 09:33:00';
var time = '00:00:23';
var result = datetime + time; // I know this is wrong
```

How can I add the two variables so that the result will be

```
2020/09/21 09:33:23
```

Comment: I think you have misread the data. Your datetime should be in the format yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm:ss. So did you actually want ```2020/09.21 9:33:23``` as your output? Or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: `00:00:23` is what? ??:HH:MM ??

Comment: that should be actually `var datetime = '2020/09/21 00:09:33';`

Comment: You are defining strings, so the `+` will just concatenate. You need the `Date` object. See @Derek.W solution below

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add 30 minutes to a JavaScript Date object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1197928/how-to-add-30-minutes-to-a-javascript-date-object)

Comment: sorry I was wrong, that should be `var datetime = '2020/09/21 09:33:00';`

Answer (score 3):

```
var date = new Date('2020/09/21 9:33');
var time = 23 * 1000;  // in miliseconds
var result = new Date(date.getTime() + time);
```

Comment: what if this is the given time? `var time = '00:25:54';` // you mean convert this to milliseconds?

Comment: Yes. Need to convert to miliseconds like this. `var time = (25 * 60 + 54) * 1000;`

Comment: Should be `var time = new Date('1970/01/01 ' + '00:00:23' + ' GMT+0');`, then use `time.getTime()`

Answer (score 0):

So you need to calculate number of seconds and add it to the date

```js
const datetime = '2020/09/21 00:09:33';
const time = '00:00:23';
const parts = time.split(":");
const seconds = +parts[0] * 3600 + +parts[1] * 60 + +parts[2];
const date = new Date(datetime);
date.setSeconds(date.getSeconds() + seconds);

console.log(date.toLocaleString())
```