# Auto populate finish time textbox 15 mins from start time

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have 2 textbox, `Start_time` and `Finish_time`, when i pick time lets say 12:00:00 using jquery time picker, the Finish time should show 12:15:00 automatically.any help? much appreciated. I tried so many javascript code but it doesn't work. im using 24 hr format.

```
<html>
            
           <div>
           <input  type="text" name="start_time" id="start_time"> 
           <div>
           
            <div>
         <input  type="text" name="finish_time" id="finish_time" readonly>
         </div>
      </html>
```

Comment: Please provide some code so we can see your problem

Comment: Can you show your progress? A part of the code perhaps. It helps us know the problem more

Comment: i had a code here but before proceeding to finish time, i need to manually pick 15 mins to meeting length.

Comment: Please read https://idownvotedbecau.se/nocode https://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking

Answer (score 0):

This plugin stores chosen time in the list, precisely, in element with id: `#ui-active-item`
. When you know this, just some time manipulation is left.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#start_time').timepicker({
        timeFormat: 'HH:mm ss',
        interval: 1,
        minTime: '10',
        maxTime: '6:00pm',
        defaultTime: '11',
        startTime: '10:00',
        dynamic: false,
        dropdown: true,
        scrollbar: true
    });
    $('#start_time').blur(function() {
        console.log($('#ui-active-item').text());
        time = new Date($('#ui-active-item').text());
        final = new Date(time.getTime() + 15 * 60000);
        timer = final.toLocaleTimeString('it-IT')
        $('#finish_time').val(timer)
    })
});
```

DEMO:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#start_time').timepicker({
        timeFormat: 'HH:mm ss',
        interval: 1,
        minTime: '10',
        maxTime: '6:00pm',
        defaultTime: '11',
        startTime: '10:00',
        dynamic: false,
        dropdown: true,
        scrollbar: true
    });
    $('#start_time').blur(function() {
        console.log($('#ui-active-item').text());
        time = new Date($('#ui-active-item').text());
        final = new Date(time.getTime() + 15 * 60000);
        timer = final.toLocaleTimeString('it-IT')
        $('#finish_time').val(timer)
    })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/timepicker/1.3.5/jquery.timepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/timepicker/1.3.5/jquery.timepicker.min.js"></script>

<input  type="text" name="start_time" id="start_time"> 
<input  type="text" name="finish_time" id="finish_time" readonly>
```

Great help was: [How to add 30 minutes to a JavaScript Date object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1197928/how-to-add-30-minutes-to-a-javascript-date-object)

Comment: thankyou so much for your help i really need this :) it shows invalid date on me but i think it's just because of the time format. thankyou so much

Comment: can i change it to HH:mm:ss?

Comment: Hmmm....  not sure, but you can convert other date to HH: mm ss?

Comment: any suggestion to fix that?

Comment: Hm... not sure, plugin code should be checked, and changed, eventually...

Comment: hmm okay, I'll try to fix it. thankyou so much for your help  :)