# How to add days to today? javascript

Tags: javascript

How to add days to today in day-month-year format?
I tried this code but additionally get the time zone and month in the short word name.
I want to receive, for example, August 12, 2023
here is the code:

```js
Date.prototype.addDays = function(days) {
  var date = new Date(this.valueOf());
  date.setDate(date.getDate() + days);
  return date;
}

var date = new Date();

console.log(date.addDays(5));
```

Comment: Already answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1197928/how-to-add-30-minutes-to-a-javascript-date-object

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I format a date in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552461/how-do-i-format-a-date-in-javascript)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the format: `Month Day, Year`, Simply use **ECMAScript Internationalization API**:

```js
return date.toLocaleString('en-us',{month:'long', year:'numeric', day:'numeric'})
```

```
month:'long' //August
day:'numeric' //12
year:'numeric' //2023
```

*Note: 'long' uses the full name of the month, 'short' for the short name,*

Answer (score 1):

Create an array of months

```js
var months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];
```

In the function `Date.prototype.addDays`, return the date string as

```js
return months[date.getMonth()] + " " + date.getDate() + ", " + date.getFullYear();
```

Output:

```js
July 15, 2022
```

Answer (score 0):

You are adding 2 dates in the correct way, there is the only problem in outputting the date in desired format. You can format the date as follow based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34015511/15438360):

```js
Date.prototype.addDays = function(days) {
  var date = new Date(this.valueOf());
  date.setDate(date.getDate() + days);
  
  // return formatted date
  var options = {year: 'numeric', month: 'long', day: 'numeric' };
  return date.toLocaleDateString("en-US", options);
}

var date = new Date();

console.log(date.addDays(5));
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is twofold:

1. how to add days to a date
2. and how to format a date

#### 1. adding days

the easiest way to do simple calculations with date and time values is to transform all date and time into UNIX timestamps (number of milliseconds since the january 1st 1970 epoch) then adding and substracting days or calculating date differences is simply adding and substracting integer numbers.

For example.

to obtain the unix time of right now just use `Date.now()` which is *1657452836534*
five days in millisecods is `5*24*60*60*1000`
thus five days ahead of now is `Date.now() + 5*24*60*60*1000` which is *1657884836534*
to obtain a `Date` object, you need to create one with the timestamp value `new Date(Date.now() + 5*24*60*60*1000)`

#### 2. format Date

formatting Dates is more complex that it seems, as there are some subtle issues around, depending on users cultural conventions. See [How do I format a date in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552461/how-do-i-format-a-date-in-javascript) for a detailed answer. But as a show answer if you want your code to work for any user, the easiest way it to use native javascript `toLocaleDateString()` function. See
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString .

wrapping up, for your case, try

```
new Date(Date.now()+5*24*60*60*1000).toLocaleDateString()
```