# javascript add number of input fields equal to the number of months

Tags: javascript

I have two input fields with date1 and date2.Below this two fields i need a button that when i press it, will create a number of input fields equal to the number of months between the 2 date fields.
For example i have date1=2012-03-21 and dat2=2012-06-21. It should generate 3 input fields
 Can you help me with this one?

Comment: this is a pretty interesting question.  are you using any libraries? jquery?  date.js?

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume the HTML looks something like this:

```
<div id="dateRange">
    <input type="text" id="startDate">
    <input type="text" id="endDate">
</div>
<div id="monthlyEntries"/>
```

Now, a month is not a uniform number of days ("30 days has September, April, June,and November..."), so I'm *guessing* the day portion of the dates don't matter.

Then, the javascript to call on change (or clicking a button, or whatever), would look something like this:

```
function buildMonthlyEntries() {
    var startDate = new Date(document.getElementById('startDate').value);
    var endDate = new Date(document.getElementById('endDate').value);
    if(startDate == "Invalid Date" || endDate == "Invalid Date") { return null; }
    var entryCount = (endDate.getMonth() + endDate.getFullYear()*12) - (startDate.getMonth() + startDate.getFullYear()*12);
    var monthlyEntries = document.getElementById('monthlyEntries');
    monthlyEntries.innerHTML = "";
    for(var i = 0; i < entryCount; i++) {
        var textElement = document.createElement('input');
        textElement.setAttribute('type', 'text');
        textElement.setAttribute('id', 'entry' + i);
        monthlyEntries.appendChild(textElement);
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: one problem, if i add different year it doesn`t generate the corect number of input fields. Can this script be modified to also calculate if i change the year? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can run a loop based upon the difference in the dates. In pseudo code it would be something like

```
var difference = month2 - month1;

for(x=0;x<difference,x++){
     add inputfield;
}
```

Comment: it would be very usefull to me a complete answer because i don`t know javascript very good

Comment: Please check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4944750/how-to-subtract-date-time-in-javascript or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/674721/how-do-i-subtract-minutes-from-a-date-in-javascript or http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/datedifference.shtml or search google for javascript date subtract for a ton of results.