# Javascript date format conversion

Tags: javascript, datetime

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Convert UTC Epoch to local date with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4631928/convert-utc-epoch-to-local-date-with-javascript)

In my project,
I am receiving a JSON. it contains one field like

```
"displayDate":"1349137055814",
```

How can I convert to user readable (understandable, to be specific ;) ) form?
For eg mm-dd-yyyy

And what is this format?

Comment: So millisecond epoch time; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4631928/convert-utc-epoch-to-local-date-with-javascript

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/847185/convert-a-unix-timestamp-to-time-in-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[new Date(milliseconds)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#section_10) creates a new date object using your millseconds value.

You can then use getYear, getDate, toLocaleFormat() or [toUTCString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toUTCString) to get your correct format.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert it to a date using the Javascript Date object.

```
// Assuming 'result' contains your JSON

var myDate = new Date(result.displayDate);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use it this way

```
var d = new Date(1349137055814);
alert(d.getMonth()+ '/' + d.getDate() + '/' + d.getFullYear());
```

Check this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Qq9wv/)