# Simple Hour Countdown

Tags: javascript, countdown

I am trying to do this kind of countdown:

Now it is 09:20 and I am wanna how many minutes and seconds has left to 1 hour. So it would take 40 minutes to 10:00.

This countdown has to continuously count this gap within the day.

I've tried the following but it didn't work:

```
var now = new Date();
var mins = now.getMinutes();
var secs = now.getSeconds();

function initClock(id) {
  const counter = document.getElementById(id);

  const minutesItem = counter.querySelector('.js-countdown-minutes');
  const secondsItem = counter.querySelector('.js-countdown-seconds');

  function updateClock() {
    mins = now.getMinutes();
    secs = now.getSeconds();

    minutesItem.innerHTML = (60 - mins);
    secondsItem.innerHTML = (secs);

  }

  updateClock();
  const timeinterval = setInterval(updateClock, 1000);
}

initClock('js-countdown');
```

The Seconds aren't being updated.

Comment: pls share html also..

Comment: When saying _it didn't work_ it's better to say what didn't work

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I make a program that reads the date(hour,minutes,seconds) then it subtracts it from the second date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46973205/how-can-i-make-a-program-that-reads-the-datehour-minutes-seconds-then-it-subtr)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to redecalre `now = new Date();`. 
It's not getting update on every `updateClock()` iteration.

The code fixed :

```
function initClock(id, endtime) {
  const counter = document.getElementById(id);

  const minutesItem = counter.querySelector('.js-countdown-minutes');
  const secondsItem = counter.querySelector('.js-countdown-seconds');

  function updateClock() {
    var now = new Date(),
        mins = now.getMinutes(),
        secs = now.getSeconds();

    minutesItem.innerHTML = (60 - mins);
    secondsItem.innerHTML = (secs);

  }

  updateClock();
  const timeinterval = setInterval(updateClock, 1000);
}

initClock('js-countdown', 3600);
```

And by the way, those first three lines :

```
var now = new Date();
var mins = now.getMinutes();
var secs = now.getSeconds();
```

are unneeded.

Comment: Thanks! Sorry for this elementary mistake. Still new to Javascript.

Comment: No problem, please check this as the right answer if that fixed your problem !

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this countdown, you can use this function to get the counter result.

```js
function getCountDown(initDate) {
 // Get todays date and time
  var now = new Date().getTime();

  // Find the distance between now an the count down date
  var distance = initDate - now;

  // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
  var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
  var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
  var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

  // Display the result in the element with id="demo"
  return days + "d " + hours + "h "
  + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s "
}
// Set the date we're counting down to

var countDownDate = new Date("Jan 5, 2018 15:37:25").getTime();
var strCounDown = getCountDown(countDownDate)

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = strCounDown;
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

The goal you want to achieve isn't well described to be honest. But if you want your counter to be constantly updated, you have to update `now` variable every time `updateClock` function is called. So, you need to put this:

```
var now = new Date();
var mins = now.getMinutes();
var secs = now.getSeconds();
```

inside your `updateClock` function. Thus, you won't need those lines in the beginning of your code. Besides that, I don't understand why you have `endtime` argument for `initClock` function, as you never use it.

Btw, perhaps you want to change `secondsItem.innerHTML = (secs);` to `secondsItem.innerHTML = (60 - secs);` if it's a countdown as you say.

Comment: Sorry. English is not my first language. ):

As for the seconds, you are correct. Thanks.