# Get past 5 minutes in easier way , javascript

Tags: javascript

I want array of past five minutes in `hour:minute` format like below , But is there any other smarter way to do it easily ?

```
     var today = new Date();
     today.setSeconds(0);
     var last1 = new Date(today.getTime() - (1000*60));

     hour = last1.getHours();
     min = last1.getMinutes();
     final1 = hour+":"+min;

     var last2 = new Date(today.getTime() - (1000*120));
     var last3 = new Date(today.getTime() - (1000*180));
     var last4 = new Date(today.getTime() - (1000*240));
     var last5 = new Date(today.getTime() - (1000*300));

     var arr = [final1,final2,..and so on];
```

Comment: [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Comment: @MaheerAli `final1` is there. Hence `final2`, etc. should be in the same format.

Comment: final 2 , 3 , 4 , 5 etc same logic , since it will increase length of the code , I ignored for easy understanding.

Comment: `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5].map(function(i) { return new Date(new Date().getTime() - (1000 * 60 * i)) })`

Comment: @fqhv Why not just post that as an answer?

Comment: @fqhv OP wants `hh:mm` formatted output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd start by creating a reusable `subtractMinutes` function.

You could then create a new array of `5` items and use that `subtractMinutes` on each. The first item would have `0` minutes subtracted, the second would have `1` minute subtracted, so-on and so-forth.

```js
const subtractMinutes = (date,minutes) => new Date(date - minutes * 60000);

const getPastMinutes = (minutes, startDate = new Date()) => {
  return [...Array(minutes)].map((i,idx) => {
    let newDate = subtractMinutes(startDate,idx);
    let hour = newDate.getHours().toString().padStart(2,'0');
    let minute = newDate.getMinutes().toString().padStart(2,'0');
    return `${hour}:${minute}`;
  });
};

console.log( getPastMinutes(5) );
```

Related documentation, references:

- [`new Date(date - minutes * 60000)`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/674735/2026606) to subtract minutes from a date
- [`[...Array(minutes)].map()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39879146/2026606) to create a new array of `n` length
- [`` `${hour}:${minute}` ``](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) for string concatenation
- [`String.padStart`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart) to pad single-digit values (e.g. preventing `01:05` from appearing as `1:5`)