# Subtract hours from date and time

Tags: javascript, datetime

Could someone help me with this. I need to finish something for a schoolproject which we are displaying tonight and I have to subtract 2 hours from this code. Javascript is totally not my thing.

```
<a href="urltopage.php"><span id="datetime"></span></a>

<script>
var dt = new Date();
document.getElementById("datetime").innerHTML = dt.toLocaleString();
</script>
```

I have no idea how to change this. Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Justin

Comment: What have you tried? I'm sure there are dozens of question on this site that have example of what you want. First result from a search is: [How do I subtract minutes from a date in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/674721/how-do-i-subtract-minutes-from-a-date-in-javascript) Which could be modified to hours.

Comment: let dt = new Date(Date.now() - 7200); 7200 = 60sec per minute * 60 minutes * 2.

Answer (score 5):

Try

```js
var dt = new Date();
dt.setHours(dt.getHours() - 2);
document.getElementById("datetime").innerHTML = dt.toLocaleString();
```

Have a look here https://codepen.io/vyspiansky/pen/abNBqrx

Comment: you are my HERO! Thank you so much! Just one quick additional question. What if I would want to subtract 2 hours and 7 minutes?

Comment: I guess, `dt.setMinutes(dt.getMinutes() - 7);` should help to achieve this goal. Demo - https://codepen.io/vyspiansky/pen/KKzNoPR

Comment: I tried that, but guess I had a typo because it didn't work. But now it does, stupid me. You are truly my hero and saved me from a lot of searching. Thanks so much!

Answer (score -2):

You can use [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/).

```
moment(dt).subtract(2, 'hours').format();
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. But like I said, I have no knowledge of Javascript. So how do I implement this in my current script?

Comment: using `moment` is a good solution

Comment: Moment is a good library for handling time but I would argue it really isn't necessary for a one off date manipulation.

Comment: You can use a JS file that you can refer on the page via a CDN. I.e. `<script src="https://cdnjs.com/libraries/moment.js"></script>`

Comment: Moment is deprecated, do not use on new projects.